# Modify question text to include "Migrated to ..." after migration so that it shows up in the excerpt when browswing questions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Instead of [closed] for migrated questions, [migrated]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10641/instead-of-closed-for-migrated-questions-migrated)

When we migrate a question [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557/how-does-stackoverflow-work-the-official-faq-closed) to another site, can you modify the first line or two of the question to say "Migrated to ..." so that when viewed in the [question list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes), the excerpt or blurb would indicate that it is migrated.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10641

Comment: I think that changing [closed] to [migrated] is a cleaner, more visible solution than editing the post.

Comment: OK, it's close enough to 10641 that I'm closing as a duplicate (even though the suggested solutions are very slightly different)

Comment: Gah .. just had to go through a Captcha that say 'Philadelphia'. How on earth do you expect me to spell that?

Answer (score 0):

Already Asked... Yesterday

From Eric's Comment: [For migrated questions, append {migrated} to the title, instead of {closed}](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10641) (He seems to love posting links to duplicates)

Comment: It's my hobby. Also my hobby: Participating in somebody else's phone conversations. I call it, "What phone?"

Comment: Why do I have a feeling you aren't kidding?

Comment: @Chacha102: It could be worse - there are users that flag a post for moderator attention every time they discover a dupe.

Comment: @Kyle, No I meant about the Phone Conversation thing...

Comment: @Chacha: I was only kidding about the first hobby :)

Comment: I point once again to this thread: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5314/should-sarcasm-be-forbidden

Comment: @Kyle - When you don't have the rep to vote as duplicate, what alternative is there?

Comment: @Kyle - Nevermind - Would help if I read the FAQ - My apologies

Comment: @Diago: I was sort of tongue-in-cheek earlier, but it seems like there has been a bit of overuse of the flag-for-moderator to close duplicates recently. I've chalked this up to the fact that the site's relatively new and that there are only a handful of people with the rep to close, so I hope it will get better in the future.