# Is campaigning acceptable?

Tags: discussion, ethics, nominations

For [nominees](https://stackoverflow.com/users/vote-moderator) who are actively answering questions, is it acceptable for them to mention their nomination in comments when others express an appreciation for their efforts?

Comment: @Jonathan: Only if you do something like add the following to the footer of all your posts...  "I bring both the grease and the monkey to the table and that is why I'm running for SO moderator.  I am Jonathan Sampson and I approve this message"   Oh and by the way... This is a horrible idea!

Comment: For the record, you got my vote
because I like your involvement and interaction with folks.

Comment: @Chester: I appreciate it!

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with mentioning it on your user page, which is likely to be visited by someone who really appreciated one of your answers anyway.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'd suggest not.  Self-promotion in other contexts in SO usually leaves a bad taste.  Let your work speak for itself.

Answer (score 15):

I wouldn't do it myself. If it has nothing to do with answering the question, **it's just noise**.

It just seems tacky. Then again, that's probably why I am not going to win.

Comment: +1 I lean towards this same opinion.

Comment: Well, that and those photos that I have of you that will be accidentally leaked the day before the close of the election...

Comment: *"I lean towards this same opinion."* -- That it's tacky *or* that I am not going to win?

Comment: @Robert: The former :)

Comment: @Geoffrey The only problem with that plan, is that most people will have voted already.

Comment: @Brad: Who said I cared about the election?

Answer (score 14):

No way, man. You gotta tell them to vote for you *before* you give them an answer. Maybe even withhold it 'till they post a screenshot of the voting page, with the big **1** next to your name...

Comment: I like how this has gotten downvotes despite the clear sarcasm.

Comment: Sarcasm is unprofessional, and has no place on a site like this. Some of us are here to get answers to important questions, or discuss the future direction of the site in suitably serious tones.

Comment: @Shog9: And those answers and questions will one day make you qualified to be a moderator.

Comment: Don't forget, the very mod candidate that this answer is to, is the one who wants to ban sarcasm: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5314/ban-sarcasm

Comment: Dammit, man... It's only funny if it's *subtle*.

Comment: @Shog9: Careful, if you mention a deity on that word, that is damnable as well.

Answer (score 6):

Come on - let's have some campaign slogans. Does anyone remember Barry Goldwater's (1960's Republican maniac) classic:

> In your heart, you know he's right!

and his opposition's rejoinder:

> In your guts, you know he's nuts!

Comment: If you think he's nuts, kick him in the n...

Comment: ... heart?  c'mon, don't leave us hanging here!

Comment: @Pollyanna - Where's my nheart?

Comment: @Changing: That's the next great framework from the alt.net folks. Due in 6 - 8 weeks.

Answer (score 3):

I think that it would hurt more than it would help. It's a bit tacky, and *I* wouldn't consider voting on someone who does that, if I knew nothing else about him. Others might react differently.

Besides, is it really such a big deal? Do you really want to have more responsibilities on the site and an obligation to be logged on as much as possible? Sure, we do it anyway, but as a hobby. If you win the election, great, if not, what did you lose?

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider it acceptable in a comment, *maybe*, and especially if you went back and deleted all these comments after the election is over...

Answer (score 1):

No.  Comments should be relevant to the question or answer to which they are attached.  Anything else is just spam, is likely to be flagged as such, and may actually hurt your chances in the long run.

Comment: Primarily because those comments will last years in the system, attached to questions and answers to which they add absolutely no value.