# SO community sarcasm

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, community

1. On a scale of 1 to 10 how sarcastic
   is the community, in your opinion?
2. Why do you think that is so?
3. Should sarcasm be rewarded or
   discouraged?
4. How to implement bullet 3

**Answer example:**

- 9.67
- Dumb questions bring out the devil in
  me.
- rewarded!!!
- add reputation points for sarcasm

Comment: Sarcastic? Not so much. I see a lot of narky users on ServerFault, but it's usually isolated incidences (i.e. all first offences all by different people, usually on stupid questions). We all have bad days!

Comment: Is this question asked out of pure curiosity or have you been bothered by someone?

Comment: @Alex: a bit of both but the catalyst had been the latter reason...

Comment: @Yaneeve if you deem something abusive flag it for moderator attention. But remember, we all add a pinch of sarcasm at times, although it's not always intended to sting.

Comment: @Alex: I had flagged it

Comment: What example brought you here?

Comment: @random: Perhaps it is my over sensitivity, yet here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616650/how-mature-is-apache-sshd-mina/2653086#2653086

Comment: @random: That is a question I asked about a general matter. I think that these types of questions should be valid for SO...

Comment: Your example was a non-answer to a poor question. No sarcasm there.

Comment: @random: if the question was/is poor and if general matters are of no interest to SO users then, it is my opinion that, SO should be renamed to: "The site which provides free answers (as opposed to EE) to extremely specific questions which are of interest to but a few people and which reward experienced users with addicting reputation points"

Comment: You're correct, SOFU is not a community discussion forum.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5314/should-sarcasm-be-acceptable.

Comment: Oh, a complaint about *sarcasm*.  That's a *real* useful topic.

Comment: @Aarobot - you should totally drop your sarcasm and use jQuery.

Comment: @Aarobot, I see what you did there.  {Chuckle}  However even back in 2010, cruelty toward noobs was a severe problem IMO, so a sarcasm question.......not a problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On meta?

9.99999
It's meta.
Rewarded
We already vote up sarcasm.

On SO?

1.2
It's heavily moderated by the community
Discouraged
It's low enough that we can't force it any lower

Comment: Hmm.. but this brings up one of those logical problems like "Everything I say is a lie".... is this post on meta sarcastic? Is Meta really the serious one and SO is sarcastic?....

Comment: @Billy: I'll leave that up to your judgement. There's a .001% chance, according to my statistics, that a randomly selected post on Meta will be serious.

Comment: @waiwai933 according to your own answer the statistic should be at no more than 0.00001%

Comment: @yaneeve: The '%' sign, as dictated in mathematics, has an implied division by 100. That is, there is a .001/100 chance that a post will be serious.

Comment: @waiwai933: it's early morning where I am, perhaps you are right

Comment: waiwai933: Except the probability of your statement that the stat is .001% has a probability of .001% (by self reference), for a total likelihood of seriousness of .00001%

Comment: @Billy: Who says that sarcasm and seriousness are mutual exclusive?

Comment: @Ladybug: They're not, but sarcasm does set the tone. Question is, is that tone wanted/accepted?

Answer (score 9):

Obligatory Simpsons reference:

> **User420815:** whats code 4 mking game w/ super unicorns plz help
>   **Neil Fatvalue:** Bravo, that's a great question.
>   **Spoel Jolsky:** Oh, isn't that sweet. Even Neil's adding his kudos!
>   **Neil Fatvalue:** I was being sarcastic!
>   **Spoel Jolsky:** You were?
>   **Neil Fatvalue:** No, I was being sincere!
>   **Jeff Nearforest:** Oh, i'm so confused!

Answer (score 4):

Like you're going to do anything with the answers anyway!

Comment: Could vote them up...

Answer (score 3):

- ~1.5
- Badly asked questions beg for bad answers.  I think we all try to be polite but occasionally people get frustrated about badly asked questions and offer an answer that isn't that helpful.  Downvote or flag it if you think it deserves it.

  - IMHO, your example question is badly asked, it is somewhat subjective, and you could find most of what you want to know by taking a quick look at the web site and mailling lists.
- Depends, sometimes it is better to just ignore it.  It is very rarely rewarded.
- Down-voting, and flagging are adequate responses 99% of the time.

For the record sometimes sarcastic answers are [great](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: I don't see how the regex answer is sarcastic. It's a completely correct answer with a bit of melodrama thrown in for effect.

Comment: @mmyers: Maybe sarcastic is the wrong word.  Though it does seem to attempt to express humorous contempt about using regex to parse html which does seem to fit some definitions of sarcasm.

Answer (score 1):

1. 0
2. We're all totally living The New Sincerity
3. Encouraged, for sure. Nothing makes you feel more comfortable and accepted like an intentionally factitious answer.
4. Motivational speakers. Lots of them.

Comment: -1 for mentioning motivational speakers. You just totally removed all my motivation to fill out a cover sheet for my TPS report :(