# Disallowing questions that can be easily googled or answered by RTFM

Tags: discussion, questions

It appears to me that SO is inundated with questions which can answered by a trivial google search or by perusing the documentation.  I'm not talking about 1 or 2 out of 100, but like 20-25% of the questions are of this type.  My feeling is that SO is devaluing itself by allowing these questions.  If SO wants to continue to be a truly "expert" forum it might be prudent by following the custom of some language centric irc channels and not tolerating questions that can easily be answered by some effort in reading or searching on the part of the questioner.  Continuing to allow these questions dilutes the quality of SO and may even sink it to irrelevance.

Comment: Questions like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003841/how-do-i-move-the-turtle-in-logo ... its never going to happen, for quite a few good reasons

Comment: The goal of sites like this is to attract users, not to repel them.

Comment: Read The Friendly FAQ!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The point is to build a database of Q&A so that Google will always find it here.

Comment: I agree in the case where the answer is "easily found" on another site via Google. I disagree for exact RTFM questions, however. Stack Overflow should explicitly _not_ have as its goal that the content of every manual and guide will eventually be copy/pasted into it as an answer.

Comment: @Phrogz, sure, not every manual and guide, but have you ever had to find important stuff in MSDN?  What a headache that is.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that Google doesn't have ANY answers. It sends you to other sites with answers. SO wants to be that site.

Answer (score 0):

See [Embrace the non-Googlers…](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers) and [How to deal with google questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-to-deal-with-google-questions)

Comment: Your second link was migrated here, can you update the link?

Comment: @Kevin - Link updated.

Answer (score -1):

I think it may have been in one of the podcasts (sorry, can't remember which) and Jeff/Joel spoke about how they want SO to have answers to questions of ANY level, even super-noob questions ('What is a variable?' type stuff) even if they have been answered previously on another website/resource.

Answer (score -2):

**Edit: I was being sarcastic!**

Google can find anything so why don't we just stop using SO?

Comment: Well, we know the answer is 42, but what is the question? I googled it and it couldn't tell me.

Comment: Try Wolfram Alpha