# Is it inappropriate to ask a user to google in comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, google

I know that it is bad to ask [google searchable questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33376/is-it-bad-to-ask-google-searchable-questions), however, this still happens more often than not on the some of the sites.

I also know that [LGTMFY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links) is inappropriate, is it appropriate to tell the OP to "just google that" or "just search google" in a comment?

It seems to me that this is also inappropriate and there are better approaches to take.

Comment: some mods are saying in chat that many comments (made with good intention are flagged as rude) Comments like _is your google broken_ may be flagged

Comment: You know, you should just google this.

Comment: ^Doesn't come across as nice, and could end up being completely useless if the top results are all Stack questions with the same comment and no answers. If you have specific search terms to suggest to help teach the user how better to search, _and_ you can word it politely, that's more useful.

Comment: @SoMeUsEr Mods are pretty likely to remove it anyway, but you can sure try.  You might get lucky and have it not be flagged.  Telling people things they don't want to hear (like you could have searched google instead of asking a question that violates SE's quality standards) is likely to get your comment removed, no matter how useful, constructive, or polite it's worded.

Comment: most probably such comments will gone along with the question :D @Servy

Comment: Links to search result pages aren't better than LGTMFY @SoMeUsEr, please avoid them. Also, there's no guarantee that everyone will see the same results.

Comment: @SoMeUsEr One would hope, but such hopes are often in vain.  Depends somewhat on the tag, time of day, and how lucky you are.  In many situations you'll instead just see the question get answers duplicating what was in the top search results (at best, more likely they'll be of lower quality than what's already there), and both the question and answers will get upvotes.

Comment: @yannis There's no reason to avoid them at all.  It's providing an answer to the question.  Avoiding providing a correct answer to the question isn't helpful.

Comment: I guess we have vastly different definitions of what constitutes an answer then @Servy.

Comment: @yannis We're not talking about answers.  We're talking about comments.  Of course a link to a google search doesn't constitute an answer.  Comments aren't *supposed* to constitute answers.

Comment: @Servy "It's providing an answer to the question"

Comment: @Servy Why suggest people to do something "mods are likely to remove..." just to see if they can get away with it. Just makes more work for everyone. We're discussion preferred behaviors here.

Comment: @yannis And it is, indirectly.  In the same way that closing as a duplicate provides an answer to the question, even though linking to a duplicate question doesn't constitute an appropriate answer if you were to post it as one.

Comment: @RobertCartaino I'm suggesting that the behavior is beneficial, and that mods are incorrect to remove it, but pointing out that the mods are likely to remove these beneficial contributions anyway, so it's probably not worth posting these useful contributions if you're worried about them being removed.

Answer (score 6):

Yes.

Much more effective is down voting the question for lack of research, as well as not being useful for future visitors.

[image]

Next step is to verify if the question fits one of the close reasons. Often too broad or unclear are appropriate choices for these type of question. The OP will get an inbox message that their question received a close vote and once a closed a post notice will contain links to articles in the help center. Questions that are closed and down voted will be deleted by the [Roomba process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/roomba).

If you do know the question has an answer on Google, you might as well go the extra mile and find a duplicate that is applicable. The benefit of that option is that the OP will get their answer, hopefully notice the much better question/answers, and the post could be hammered by a gold badge holder, closing it early, preventing (low quality) answers.

If you really insist on leaving a comment, make sure you guide to user to resources that help them to [improve their question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136609/repository-of-useful-pro-forma-comments). You could point them to `[ask]` (see [comment magic links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000)) or verify if they found a particular post/wiki/blog/documentation and if they did, let them elaborate why the solution found there didn't work in their context. Always suggest they edit their post as some new users are so used to a thread based conversation that they never noticed the edit link under their question.

Paraphrasing what a CM once said: If you leave a comment you need to be prepared to engage in a conversation with the OP. If your only aim is to have a chuckle about your witty-ness , refrain from commenting at all.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how a comment saying "just google that" is helpful.

If you don't feel the question is worth the effort of writing a comment that will actually help improve it, then just downvote it and move on. I think that's better for everyone involved.

Comment: It *is* helping improve the question though.  It's giving the question author information on what a problem with their question is, and how to fix it, as well as how they can get the answer to their question.

Comment: I think "hey just google it" is not constructive, and "please do some research" is. But I've seen enough google comments to bring it up here