# Propose a new 20k reputation privilege

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, reputation, privileges

Right now, the maximum privilege "unlock" is at 10k reputation:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges

We're considering adding a new 20k reputation privilege, but having a hard time figuring out exactly what it should be.

Two guidelines:

1. I would like it to be **more than cosmetic** -- I'd prefer to add a new and useful privilege that gives people actual power to effect more change on the site they have invested so much time in.
2. It would also be clever, though by no means required, **if the privilege *scaled*** so the more reputation you get above 20k, the more potent this hypothetical privilege is. Although this could be risky and even dangerous, so be careful and think through the  consequences of what you're proposing.

Let's hear it -- please propose a new 20k reputation privilege,  ideally meeting at least one of the guidelines above!

Comment: This is the last thing that I, a 9665-rep user, needed to see. I'm already hooked, man!

Comment: Lol, most of these answers are by users between 19-21K rep here on meta.

Comment: I don't think that 20k rep users are more thrustworthy than 10k users. I believe after 10k one has proven one's dedication and that one knows the way around SO. I'd rather give the proposed priviledges directly to 10k users. At the moment, they don't gain much power.

Comment: @Georg: When you have as many users above 20k as SO has (which correlates to the number of users total), it might be worth giving them some additional privileges to *reduce moderator load* — and I think that should be the goal of any of these high-rep privileges.  SO is getting a lot more 10kers, and the specific rep requirement is higher to both reduce the number of users (thus hopefully avoid some abuse) and make it meaningful+fun.  The latter includes not swamping users with a ton of new abilities at once, which is already a problem with 10k.

Comment: I'm not saying these users should be forced to spend more of their time moderating, but if they want to, giving them the tools to do so is a good thing.  I'm using "moderation" broadly as "actual power to effect change" rather than specifically limiting other users; e.g. tag synonyms are change without limiting other users (but they'd also make a bad 20k ability, I think).

Comment: This list of privileges that 10k users don't have is useful: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/

Comment: I propose the *inability to answer questions that don't already have several answers*. This is to take the stress of always needing to be the first to give a decent answer off their backs. (With the added bonus that other people on stackoverflow also get a chance to contribute) ;)

Comment: @Joren that would just increase the number of bounties offered. Also, Jon Skeet would kill you.

Comment: How about, the higher over 20k you are, the more points you get for upvotes, accepts ... yes I am lazily trying to increase my rep, what of it!

Comment: Jeff, shouldn't you tag this as `status-complete` already? :)

Comment: @Jeff: Why is this listed as ["Trusted user"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user), and not as three separate privileges? Other privileges that are reached at the same rep level aren't grouped together, and "trusted user" doesn't sound like a privilege, but more like a state.

Comment: Someone voted to close as No Repro, presumably because there *is* a 20k privilege now and thus no need to fill the gap… neglecting the obvious fact that it was this very question that filled that gap in the first place.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is now implemented with at least two new privilege levels:

- 15k allows users to protect questions
- 20k allows users to make edits to tag wikis without going through peer review of any kind, and also to cast delete votes against negatively voted answers. Also they can cast delete votes against a closed question regardless of its age.

Comment: I notice I can now cast delete votes on questions immediately after they're closed. Is this a 15k/20k privilege, or is it a change to the 10k delete privilege?

Comment: @bolt good point, updated

Answer (score 124):

Vote to delete answers. There is a constant stream of 'thank you notes,' snarky remarks, and other stuff which isn't formally spam but is clutter.

---

#### Edit by waffles

This is now implemented with the following caveats

1. The answer must have the score of -1 or lower
2. It requires 3 votes.

Also, the tools deleted tab has been amended to include deleted answers so we can audit this.

Comment: Deleting of crap questions was already shut down, so I don't believe we'd get this in any useful form. If it's just five votes per day or something similar it's fairly pointless, you could usually use up that amount by just going through the first two or three pages of http://stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions .

Comment: while there is no such thing as a bad question, bad answers on the other hand do exist.

Comment: Some manner of answer deletion would be helpful, especially with the stream of Thank You answers. I would much prefer to see this than to see people flag non-spam, non-offensive items improperly.

Comment: There was a `[feature-request]` about this recently - basically a non-punitive "not an answer" flag that deletes but doesn't induce a rep penalty - but I can't seem to find it.  This would seem to be a great special privilege for the 20kers.

Comment: I've been flagging these as spam, figuring other users and moderators will look at that list.  Raising the limit of 5 per day (another suggestion here) could also solve this problem.

Comment: @Grace: I've always dealt with no-purpose answers as if they were spam, because honestly, they distract from great answers - just like regular spam.

Comment: It seems to me that when I first hit 10k, I was able to vote to delete answers. There must have been some reason for removing the privilege.

Comment: @Georg: As bad as they are, they shouldn't be flagged as spam, because spam flags cause a -100 rep penalty.  Actual spamming reflects a commercial intent which justifies that penalty; people shouldn't be penalized equally for stupidity (at least not beyond the usual downvotes).  At the moment, you *should* be dealing with these by flagging them for moderator attention, not using the spam flags.

Comment: It appears that not enough 20k users are doing this for non-answers. I just deleted a -1 answer that was flagged as not-an-answer by **14 users**, and at least 2 of them were well over 40k.

Answer (score 101):

Relax or remove the daily limit of flags, close votes, and delete votes. (Did I miss any others?)

**Update:** *The number of moderator flags now depends on your rep. See [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/improved-flagging/).*

Comment: This might scale nicely - say 1 more vote per 2500 rep or something like that (starting at 20K).

Comment: Hmmm, is it really that big of a deal?

Comment: Another one that makes more work...but still on those occasions that I run out I *always* find another one I wished I'd saved up for...

Comment: I don't like this one, -1.. I think it's not really useful, especially considering the amount of reputation it requires. It would be a good privilege for something like 5k, though.

Comment: You've got a chance of hitting 20k from upvotes on this post -- well planned, sir

Comment: On SF at least this doesn't mean much. I've run out of Flags a few times, but never gotten close on close votes.

Comment: As the site grows, I find it easier and easier to run out of close votes, delete votes (now that this is rate limited), and spam flags every day.  For some reason, I found myself doing more janitorial work once I crossed the 10k threshold.  This is possibly because reputation was no longer that great of a motivator past this point, and / or I felt more invested in the site after participating for that long.

Comment: I built a tool to help me revisit closed questions after the 2 day waiting period before deletion, and found that I *really* don't have enough delete votes per day to keep up with the stuff that truly deserves deletion. I would wield more delete votes responsibly. :)

Answer (score 87):

The ability to edit comments made by other users.

Moderators already have that ability, and I find it *extremely* useful. I might entrust that power to a 20K user.

Comment: Yes! Perhaps with the option to delete comments, too.

Comment: I like this a lot, but it would require us to have a full public revision history for comments. We don't store prior comment revisions, just edit in place and increment a counter..

Comment: I'm for this only if we have better tracking of this. As it stands, we *some* history when we do it as a diamond, but it doesn't tell us what changes were made. If we want to open this up really wide, we really need better methods to track who did what.

Comment: I think this would be mostly useful for cleaning up flame wars (as opposed to typos, etc). Perhaps a very simple `comment removed by Joe "I have 20K and you don't" Smith`, rather than a full edit with revisions.

Comment: @Jon "Edit comments" vs. "Delete commments": Why don't you post that as a separate idea for voting.

Comment: @Robert - I wasn't going to steal your thunder, but this guy did: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69989/propose-a-new-20k-reputation-privilege/69999#69999

Comment: What about the ability to edit only *your own* comments at any time (no 5 minute limit)?

Comment: @JonS (I did get the right one, but for people's comprehension's sake...) A nifty ability, but that feels *really* underwhelming for a 20k privilege.

Comment: @Grace: Agreed. What I proposed could even be a 10k ability, IMO.

Comment: @JonSeigel ~ meh ... 15k or better, I think.

Comment: Even if it was just the insanely annoying 15 second **sliding** comment timer was removed I'd go for it.

Comment: To me this sounds a bit strange, you already get the priv to edit typos at 2000, why get it again at 20k

Comment: Comments are already considered a second class citizen; more attention to them (both as a 20k power and to fix minor errors) seems out of place.

Comment: @Robert: Editing will be used for deleting, just by entering 15 periods or zero-width spaces.

Comment: @RubyJunk Robert was suggesting editing **other user's comments**, high rep users still can't do that. User were always able to edit their own comments, regardless of reputation.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: *Well, actually*, it's only been possible to edit comments since [December 2009](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/459/should-we-be-allowed-to-edit-comments). But your point stands.

Comment: @mmyers hmm... well, still, I really doubt it was meant as high rep privilege.

Comment: I’d be happy with the ability to edit *my own* comments.

Answer (score 60):

The ability to protect questions, perhaps limited in the same way close votes/flags are.

*This privilege was implemented for 15k users on Feb. 9. 2011.*

Comment: this is actually a very good idea, 20K seems a reasonable limit (not too low), and using the same method as close votes makes it fair to. another great tool for the community to improve the site.

Comment: ahh, THIS is the idea we had for another 20k power way back when, and I forgot about it and was racking my brain trying to remember it. Thank you for the reminder!

Comment: I prefer the suggestion to enable (temporary) *locking* of questions, but I guess this would be the consolation prize.  I don't think that there are *that* many questions that need to be protected, because frankly I think that users with up to about 1000 rep and occasionally beyond can cause just as much trouble.

Comment: Is this useful often enough that it makes sense to build a whole voting/... infrastructure around it?

Answer (score 55):

I think this is the **wrong question** to be asking, I would rather ask:

> What work would the moderators like to
>   be able to delegate to the most
>   trusted users?

And

> What would we like the moderators to
>   do quicker?

Then see if 20K+ users or other uses can be given the power to help out.

Comment: As much as we modulate, we're really more in charge of moderation.

Comment: If you have a PU-36 explosive space modulator, that is another story. ;)

Comment: I used my privileges.

Answer (score 54):

Merging posts would be useful.

Comment: We even have history for merging. It's not very common to need (at least in new sites), but this is something I think we could safely delegate to normal users once they hit 20k.

Comment: @Grace Note: But un-merging is quite difficult, so I think I'd be cautious.

Comment: what about merging answers?

Comment: @MichaelMyers ~ If unmerging is difficult, build in a new type of vote for that process too, but only open to 20k and up?

Comment: Perhaps "participate in merge process". But this sounds like lots of work for everybody involved

Comment: @Waffles "To continue with the merge process, please fill out the following forms: ..."

Comment: Hmm. No merging privs this time. Next time, perhaps?

Comment: what do you mean? Merge 2 questions/answers? What's going to happen to the reps? Or am I not understanding this correctly?

Answer (score 53):

Let 20K users spend up to two of their close votes on a single question.

You could scale it by letting them cast an additional vote to close on a single question for  every 20K or 40K the user has. By the time they are 100K (or 200K), they can spend 5 votes on one question and close it themselves.

Comment: Aside from the abuse potential, I like this. But by the time you get to 100K (or if you're JonSkeet) you're not going to just abuse this.

Comment: Close votes are a limited resource as well, so there's a cap to the possible abuse.

Comment: oh interesting.

Comment: +1. This would be great for questions that don't get enough visibility but require closing.  However, I don't think that a non-diamond should be able to close a question in one fell swoop.  Even 100k users can get it wrong.

Comment: Start at 20K, and double it for each additional vote? 2 at 20K, 3 at 40K, 4 at 80K, and stop it there?

Comment: As an added benefit, old questions with 2 or 3 close votes have a much better chance of being seen on the 10k tools.

Comment: This could indeed be useful.  I've almost given up voting to close all of the duplicates I find regularly because you can't get the attention of others unless you get above the 2-3 vote threshold to appear in the moderator tools.

Comment: @Dra I agree: With powers like these, you are not going to "just abuse them"---you are going to **massively** abuse them! I can already see the mafias forming up around big-point honchos.

Comment: @Joel that way, you need at least 2 persons to close a question. good thinking.

Comment: From my viewpoint, this seems to deal with one of the biggest most fixable problems (the (currently) 50k+ questions with close votes). How about only 2-3 votes, but also a maximum of 2 additional votes per question for all users (i.e. max 2 users each 2 votes ((2-1)*2=2) or 1 user 3 votes (3-1=2)) (thus no question can be closed with less than 3 users). Given the quality of some 20k users, I think maybe make it higher, e.g. 50k = 2 votes, 100k = 3 votes.

Answer (score 49):

Maybe the ability to turn answers into comments and comments into answers.

This can be combined with vote for delete answers. (Migrate to comment option).

**Update:** *Converting answers into comments is now implemented for moderators.*

Comment: I was tempted to post this, but it's already been shot down as a mod feature, so I don't think they're going to add it for 20k users

Comment: @Michael: I wouldn't say it's been shot down: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35175/should-moderators-be-able-to-convert-answers-into-comments

Comment: @Jon Oh, that one went quite well. I proposed [the opposite direction](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49563/promoting-comments-to-answers) as a user option, and it didn't seem to go over very well (although looking back I guess it didn't actually get formally rejected, just the community didn't seem to like it)

Answer (score 48):

Allows users with 20K on one site to have full privileges for everything except vote to close and vote to delete across all stack exchange sites on which they have at least 200 rep (100 for account association plus 100 earned locally).

Why?  Certain skills are valid on all sites.  Earning 20K rep anywhere shows that you understand on some level what makes a good question/answer and that you know how the general system works; you ought to be able to make good edits and flags at a new site right away.  For tagging, you may not know aperture from f-stop on the photography site, but you'd know that '4.0' or '2010' probably aren't good tags anywhere, and you'd know how to fix them when you saw them.

The reason to hold back vote-to-open/close and vote-to-delete is that it takes a lot more involvement within each specific community to understand what's on-topic for that community.

This would have the pleasant side effect of helping seed new communities with privileged users faster as well.

As a side note, while I think this is a great idea, perhaps it's something to save for the 50K milestone.

An alternative that scales would be to divide rep requirements in half every time you double your rep at 20K and beyond.

Another alternative is to award an additional 100 rep for account association for each site on which you have at least 20K rep.  This would encourage participation on more sites and help give 20K users an additional leg up on new sites without giving away the farm.  So if you're 20K one one site and you associate your account to a new site, you get the base 100 for account association plus another 100 reward because you've earned 20K once: 200 total.  If you're 20K on two sites, 300 total.  The advantage here is that you wouldn't have to change the privilege calculation algorithm anywhere.

Comment: I likes this. The biggest counter-argument would be the vote to close privilege. That taken away, this might even be something for the 10k range IMO

Comment: I like this one, especially the alternative, scaling version.

Comment: A community should be policed by subject matter experts, not simply those who have some experience moderating a site.

Comment: @Pollyana - that's why the suggestion holds back those abilities that actually involve 'policing'.

Comment: No! Different sites are growing different cultures, and all the Stack Exchange sites are *qualitatively* smaller than SO with *different* needs.

Comment: May just on "new" site that don't have enough high rep users of their own yet - say just sites in beta

Comment: Absolutely not, I don't see how this scales as the topics differentiate further.

Comment: At least getting the passive privileges would be nice. Such as split-votes, view close-votes, view deleted answers,...

Answer (score 44):

This would be more of a trophy than an ability to moderate the site, but....

Vanity URLs for the person. So for example, stackoverflow.com/KyleBrandt

Comment: Shouldn't you get serverfault.com/kylebrandt before Stack Overflow?

Comment: @GraceNote: Ya, that would be the one I would get :-P

Comment: What if, eventually, there are *two* 20k+ users having the same name?

Comment: @Kenny Have user pick vanity link; first wins (which encourages people to get there faster) -- it works for Flickr, after all.

Comment: It might be worth having vanity email forwarding too, if the user opts to turn it on (so kyle.brandt@serverfault.com etc. This could also be useful for moderators so that if they have to email a user, they don't have to reveal a real email address (which may have a whois with real personal information)

Comment: I'm taking stackoverflow.com/jonskeet before he sees this discussion.

Comment: I like this idea, but I think it's unlikely to be implemented for the same reason as similar prior suggestions: it conflicts with a careers feature.

Comment: Where is that `Questions` user when we need him? Oh right, he changed his name back to `Pekka`... :-)

Answer (score 33):

Remove the rate-limiting on comments.

Comment: Never remove a rate limit! loosening it however is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: At least remove the "you need to wait 15 seconds and you only waited 14 -- timer reset. HAHAHAHAHAHAHA!"

Comment: Yeah. This would ideally be in addition to some more meaningful change, but I would certainly appreciate it anyway.

Comment: The rate limiting is per IP, not per user, so I don't think this would be possible [ http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/38947/130044 ]

Comment: +100, this is the worst bug-by-design in Stack Overflow

Comment: @michael I think of it more like this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qdFLPn30dvQ

Answer (score 30):

With 1500 rep you can edit tag wikis if you have 100 upvotes or are in the top 20 of the tag.

You could lower this threshold by increasing rep above 20k. Eventually eliminating it altogether.

Other wikis (for example the privilege wiki) can be made accessible too.

*The ability to edit any tag wiki was given to 20k users on Feb. 9. 2011. The old tag wiki editor requirements are no longer in effect.*

Comment: While I *would* trust 20k users with this, I'm not sure how useful it would be. Presumably they won't use it much *because* they're not experts in the tags in question. So I would expect grammar, speling (sic), and usage edits, but not much else. Not a bad thing, but really just another chore.

Comment: Over in p.se someone used [monitor] when there was [screen]. I was unable to set up the synonym because I had no rep in those tags. I think there is a level of rep where you can be trusted not to attempt things you don't know enough to do - eg I can decide yes on monitor/screen and "leave it alone" on some detailed tech I don't know.

Comment: @dmckee - While I would also trust 20K users with this right now, I'm not sure that I would trust them with this long term as rep inflation starts creating more and more 20K users

Comment: note that tag wikis are now powered by edit suggestions and the new 5k rep ability to approve tag wiki edits, so this is functionally implemented

Answer (score 29):

From [Are the hottest questions necessarily the right ones to feature?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69997/2509):

> Perhaps the featured questions should be hand-picked from among the hottest questions?

We could empower 20k users to cast votes for featured questions.

---

I want to address the question of "How strong would this be?". The [existing formula is documented as](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11602/2509):

```
(log(Qviews)*4) + ((Qanswers * Qscore)/5) + sum(Ascores)  
--------------------------------------------------------  
((Qage+1) - ((Qage - Qupdated)/2)) ^ 1.5
```

I propose something like

```
(log(Qviews)*4) + ((Qanswers * Qscore)/5 + Qvotes) + sum(Ascores)
------------------------------------------------------------------
((Qage+1) - ((Qage - Qupdated)/2)) ^ 1.5
```

where votes age out after a time like those to close, reopen, delete, etc. Perhaps 24 hours is a good time constant.

Any way, the point is that this would be the power to nudge question up, not the unilateral power to install them on the featured list.

I don't have a really good answer to Georg's comment, except that I think the existing system already has that problem and that this will not exacerbate it by much.

Comment: That would be bad news for obscure tags that don't have many high-rep users.

Comment: @Georg: Good point, but does the current formula do anything for them?

Comment: No. But this formula makes it worse, because by increasing the visibility of popular tags, the visibility of the less popular decreases.

Comment: @Georg: Presumably you believe there are more high rep users who concentrate on popular tags that low traffic ones. That's reasonable, and I agree. But I think that it is not the same as *"very high rep users don't read questions in obsucre tags".* I have to presume that high rep users are not going to vote to highlight every new instance of *"Why is my c++ struct bigger than it's parts?",* but rather questions that they find enlightening. And where are they likely to be enlightened? In there strong subjects or there less strong one?

Comment: I consider myself to be a high-rep user (18k), still I only participate in 13 tags, discounting tags that usually go together I'm left with about 5. I believe there are many obscure tags that don't have any high rep users. Still, you're comment made me thinking, that it might just work out perfectly. Additional, it's one of the proposals I think are really worth 20k and shouldn't be handed to 10k users.

Answer (score 27):

No more robot verification!

and/or

The ability to grafitit unicorns over any question they want to

Comment: Somebody suggested a "vote to cornify this question" button last year, I think.

Comment: Until someone hijacks a high rep user's account in a coffee shop using cookie hijacking, and then posts thousands of "answers" in a few minutes...

Answer (score 25):

Ability to delete comments. Not really clever but I think comments could use a good scrubbing now and again.

Comment: Random fact: [One out of every eight comments is a "Thank you"](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/324/number-of-comments-thanking-somebody).

Comment: @sth But not necessarily *only* thanking them; hopefully many of those are along the lines of "Thanks, but (useful comment starts here)"

Comment: Human communication does not only consist of the exchange of information: phatic communication is important too.

Comment: @sth Thank you, those stats are really useful.

Comment: I don't know how many of you were around in the early days of SO, so I'll point out here that this used to be possible for (I think) 4k+ rep users. But then it was abused and the privilege had to be removed.

Comment: I just flag meaningless comments as noise. If enough people did that, I think we'd have a lot less of those comments.

Comment: @Georg Have you seen any comments actually delete as a result of flagging?  I'll have to start doing this.

Comment: @Jay: No, but I've never went looking.

Comment: @Jay: I have, as a result of being the last to flag it.  I think it's happened twice (and I use SO a lot), but I could've been day-dreaming one of those times...  I still flag when I see them.

Comment: @sth: Is there a problem with those comments?

Comment: @Gnome: Not necessarily, though probably many of them don't add much real value. I was surprised by the high percentage.

Answer (score 24):

Remove the 2 day limit on voting to delete closed questions.

20K users should have enough about them to know when a question should be deleted rather than leaving it closed.

Obviously still have the 3 non-moderator delete votes requirement.

---

#### EDIT by waffles

This is now implemented for all 20k users.

Comment: I was originally going to oppose this, but I realize now that a lot of my perspective on this is as a diamond for Gaming. Even as diamonds we sometimes let questions sit for 2 days before deletion (as a courtesy), but that might be simply unreasonable on a high-traffic site like Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Grace - I agree some questions should be left for as long as possible before closing, but others (e.g. programming questions posted here on MSO) should be deleted immediately - they are of no use to anyone.

Comment: Even questions that are of no use to the site should have time for the OP to read comments (and answers) and possibly ask (in comments) if they don't understand or want advice on how/where to ask.  If you want to remove the 2 day limit *before voting,* okay, but not the 2 day limit before the question is actually deleted.

Comment: @Gnome - Yes it's the 2 day limit before voting I want to remove.

Comment: FWIW, I use bookmarks; I have a general category of "to look at" which includes questions that I might want to file (in the categorized folders), read, tell other people about, answer when I have more time, etc.  If it's really bad, I'll flag, otherwise deletion a week or two later (when I finally look through everything in that list) seems fine. — I don't find your suggestion bad at all (as long as it's just casting the vote), but don't find it very useful, either.  Why not give this to 10k?

Answer (score 15):

The ability to temporarily lock questions from being edited, to prevent ridiculous edit wars like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3852260/revisions). 3 votes from 20k+ users locks the post for a day or so.  Perhaps when voting to lock, pick an edit to rollback and lock to?

This would be a nice filler before a moderator notices what's going on and locks it permanently.

---

Aarobot has a good way of looking at it, *"stop the presses until a moderator looks at it"* - throws unlocking out of the window but it would be a great way of halting abuse until a moderator arrives.

Comment: That edit war is the most ridiculous thing I've ever seen

Comment: @Michael: yeah, 1 edit and 53 rollbacks in the space of an hour is pretty intense.

Comment: Then we could have a lock/unlock war before we get on to the edit war :)

Comment: @Jon B: true, but edit wars can force a question to become CW.  Lock and unlock would be 20k+ only, and would have similar restrictions as close and open like only one lock/unlock vote per question.  This would stop the same people voting again.

Comment: I like this, and I'd like to see it expanded to a full (but temporary) lock, which could also be used to halt close/reopen wars.  Have the timer set to a few hours, and if a moderator doesn't choose to permanently lock it (or decides to prematurely unlock it) then it cannot be locked again by the 20ks.  In other words, this is basically a means to stop the presses until a diamond mod can look at it.

Comment: Re: Edit - it does preclude "vote-to-unlock" and I think that's actually a good thing.  These wars happen because people get too emotionally invested in the question/answer; thus the rationale is to *take attention away* from the post and give everybody a chance to cool off.  Presumably this would also kick off an automatic moderator flag so that it's easy for a mod to cancel it in the case of abuse.  But even if a diamond mod doesn't step in, the cooling-off period would be beneficial.

Comment: This could also be handled by automatically locking any post (just for a day, as here) with X edits in N minutes.  I don't remember many false positives for X=10, N=60 (but that would include "quickly accidentally wiki'd questions"), but it would cover this case, the "bomb effing USA" troll, and several others.

Comment: [Request'd.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70122/automatically-lock-posts-heavily-edited-within-a-time-frame)

Comment: +1, giving them the ability to lock and protect posts would really be helpful.

Answer (score 15):

No really *useful* per se, but it'd be nice to get access to the site usage statistics available to moderators, view suspicious vote patterns, etc

This can even have a higher rep requirement if you will.

Comment: For a start, I'd like to view my *own* usage statistics... :(

Answer (score 15):

[Timers should not apply to 20K users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60108/disable-timers-when-user-reaches-a-certain-rep). Or even stop them at 5K.

Or, as in the question, scale them depending on rep e.g. 5K has a four second comment vote counter, 10K three seconds, etc.

Answer (score 12):

I'm not sure it's worth *looking* for privileges to grant, personally.

By the time someone's reached 20K, I'd hope they're really doing it for the love of knowledge-sharing rather than for some sort of reward - so I don't think it's needed as a "hook". I suspect you're thinking of it more as a way of giving back to regular users, but frankly the site is its own reward IMO.

I think user powers should be granted according to what the site needs, and according to who is in a best position to fulfil those needs.

Comment: I did notice a lull after the 10k point for quite a few users. So another "hook" may be a good idea.

Comment: I was thinking more of giving out more powers -- and "with great power comes great responsibility". I figure users with 20k+ have earned more of everyone's trust.

Comment: @JeffAtwood ~ I think he's commenting on the verbiage, no? You don't need to sell it as a hook.

Comment: When you have as many users above 20k as SO has (which correlates to the number of users total), it might be worth giving them some additional privileges to reduce moderator load — and I think that should be the goal of any of these privileges.  So, I agree with you in essence, but also see rep as a decent automatic judge of who is in a good position to fulfill those needs.

Answer (score 11):

The ability to put questions/answers on *hold* for a certain amount of time (maybe 30-60 minutes, that would be subject to balance).

A question/answer that is on hold can not be seen by anyone except the on who posted it and other 20k+ users.

A user can put a question/answer on hold to give the asker/answerer a chance to fix it before the closing/downvoting starts, or worse, a wrong answer gets accepted or upvoted. That means putting a question/answer on hold should always be done with a comment indicating what should be improved (fix formatting, provide information, provide links, etc.). If the question is fixed, a privileged user can take it off hold again.

The intention here is, to reduce noise, and to enforce that people actually think before they post. I think if someone is new to the site and experiences this once, he might actually learn more than if his question just gets closed.

**Second Idea**: Lower rep users can flag posts for language problems. A privileged user that speaks the native language of the poster can put the post on hold, discuss problems in the native language of the poster and help translate. This would of course require some kind of language property in the profile.

Comment: Man, I _really_ like this one. I hate seeing what I think is a reasonable question hidden in the middle of poor grammar and spelling get voted to oblivion then closed. If I'm willing to put in some work to fix it up, it'd be nice if it stood a chance of living long enough for me to finish.

Comment: .. Maybe a vote _delay_ -- allow people to cast their close votes / down votes, but _commit_ them if the post remains unchanged after an hour. If the post changed, the close / down votes evaporate or show up in a per-person queue for further consideration.

Answer (score 9):

Reset (or decrease) spam/offensive flags.

Comment: we're doing some advanced work on chat flags at the moment and we expect this will be backported to the core engine

Comment: @Jeff - VERY glad to hear it!

Comment: Would also be nice to be able to vote against a close before a Q is closed.

Answer (score 9):

Allow users with 20K+ reputation points to **see other users' deleted answers**.

Why? So that when a user complains on Meta about getting blocked by the [bad content mechanism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56817/can-we-prevent-some-of-the-low-quality-questions-from-entering-our-system/60294#60294), the entirety of 20k+ users can review the decision, and raise a flag if the blocking looks doubtful.

It's not that I distrust the team to do the right thing in blocking persistently bad question askers - not at all. I think this is the best new feature in all of SO's history. But it's an automated algorithm, and there is always the possibility of unfair blockings, or (very rarely) unjustified downvotings that lead to a blocking.

Making deleted questions visible would allow a part of the community to quality control the process. Plus I'm pretty sure people who reach 20k have become so tired of shitty questions, they are unlikely to raise hell for blocked users unless in cases where it's clear that the ruling was really, really unfair.

Comment: It's useful in general too, to see if a user with a flagged post has a history of that sort of thing so you can mod flag it

Comment: 10k users can already see deleted posts, so how is your proposal different?

Comment: @Ether deleted posts can currently be viewed only if you know the URL. The proposal is to make them visible in the user's history to 20k+ers

Answer (score 8):

Add "flagged comments" to the moderator tools.

(Frankly, this is probably fine for 10K)

**Update:** *This is now implemented in the 10k tools.*

**Update #2:** *This has been removed from 10k tools again, see: [Feedback on tools/flagged changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93623/feedback-on-tools-flagged-changes)*

Comment: Someone should fix how this reads, since it is no longer in the 10k (or 20k) tools. There should be a second update saying when it went away, perhaps with a link to the longer explanation.

Answer (score 6):

**A real idea:**

The ability to propose tag synonyms that are instantly accepted - *with the extra condition* that you need to have over 50 votes in the original tag already.

**A silly idea:**

The ability to change your display name at any time.

Comment: No matter how much reputation I have, given the possibility, I'd abuse the name changing to the infinity and beyond.

Comment: @Juan: Well that's your problem then :)

Comment: @juan How does one abuse the privilege of being able to change their display name?

Comment: @john No idea man, I posted that 7 years ago

Answer (score 5):

The ability to cornify the avatar of annoying users for 24 hours.

Comment: This would only encourage users to be annoying

Comment: @Juan many of them need no encouragement; it would probably result in a cornify war that would span decades...which I think would be vastly entertaining ;-)

Comment: Avatar cornification should be a *reward*!

Comment: Make them wear the cone of shame!

Comment: @Juan that ability is reserved for the team.

Comment: @StevenA.Lowe: Do you mean [this kind of cornify](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cornify)?

Comment: @einpoklum: yep

Answer (score 5):

Allow the gifting of reputation for exceptional questions/answers up to double what the current received rep for that question/answer is. Make it so you can gift, e.g., 5% of what you have above 20k per day, and give the user that received the gift a "gifted" badge.

Comment: And the one who gifts gets the "Santa" badge. `:)`

Comment: This is possible to do with the bounty system (under other name and UI).

Comment: @Paulo: The bounty system encourages more people to try and answer a (possibly difficult) question. It does not guarantee that you are going to get a good answer, and may even lead to you having to give the bounty to a sub par answer. Further, it is not possible to give a bounty after the question has already been answered.

Answer (score 3):

> add a new and useful privilege that gives people actual power to effect more change on the site

When I try to think of new abilities that fit this requirement, I start by looking for things that I think are broken in some way on Stack Overflow.  And, really, not much is right now.  However, there are three areas that I think could use some improvement: tagging, attention for old 'open' questions, and better handling of off-topic questions.

I'm not sure any of those could be helped with new abilities for individual users without an extensive addition to the user interface to support it (with the possible exception of perhaps making it easier for 20K users to close questions).

Comment: what do you mean "better handling of off-topic questions"

Comment: @Jeff - Right now there's lots of fail around closing Qs. Too many questions slip by, it can take a long time sometimes to close a question, and users get confused and mad because they don't understand things like 'subjective' and why other similar questions are open, or mostly they just don't like that their question was closed. Also, the simple truth is that when a new user's question is closed for any reason (even legitimate ones), it leaves them with a horrible experience on the site. Over time this could drive users elsewhere. A new 20k power might help close more Qs, but that's it.

Comment: @joel Honestly? I don't really care if question askers have a terrible experience. These users are insignificant relative to the importance of *question answerers* who do all the work in our system. In many ways the question askers are the least important users in our system, and often *harmful* users.

Comment: @Jeff - The questions are where it all starts.  If you want to think of answerers as your main audience, then question askers are the source of the content you serve to them.  Also, I don't think you have many answerers who weren't at one time primarily askers.

Comment: @joel there are a million people with a million questions. Each one thinks they are a unique snowflake. They are not. Whatever question they have, someone else will have and ask. What is unique and precious, is *people who have the answers and are willing to share them*. Common Q&A system fallacy that has destroyed many a system, so I'm happy for our competitors to keep thinking question askers are important.

Comment: that said I am happy to make closing better but *only to protect answerers*. If askers are sad that their questions are closed, well, my advice to them is to stop sucking and be awesome instead. :)

Answer (score 3):

**View Site As... Feature**

It's easy to forget what the site might look like to other users. That's why Facebook introduced the "View As..." feature:

[image]

The ability to enter a certain reputation score and then see what the site would look like would be very useful when trying to post ideas or help users on Meta. Examples:

- I want to take a screenshot to demonstrate how to access a feature, but my view of the page is cluttered with options that are not available to the average user.
- I want copy/paste an error message that high rep users don't see (you can't comment, etc).
- I'm just curious whether or not a particular feature is accessible to a user with 976, etc., reputation.

Some high-rep users and mods [create "puppet" accounts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291648/211627) to achieve this goal (being careful not to use them in fraudulent ways), but this has obvious downsides and probably isn't a good idea for the majority of 10k+/20k+ users.

If we could gain access to some sort of "view as..." feature, or official "sock puppet" accounts that are invisible to other users (with locked rep, certain restrictions, etc), it'd be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The ability to edit questions and answers in-line.

This will make our jobs of cleaning up questions and answers much easier.

[See my feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53916/inline-editing-for-stack-exchange-sites).

Comment: How is this different from the ability at 2k rep?

Comment: @drach, this will allow 'ajaxey' editing of questions and answers.  Instead of loading a new page to edit questions or answers, 20ks will be able to more quickly edit questions and answers in-line.

Comment: @drach, there is some precedence for this type of feature.  10k users get the ability to re-tag inline.

Comment: Like with some of the other suggestions, this feels a bit underwhelming for getting 20k. It really feels like something that should be gotten with 10k, if not nearer to it than *getting 10k again*. This doesn't feel like something that requires waiting for double-devotion.

Comment: I agree. This sounds more like "more work for the SE team" than "useful addition to the site as a reward for being a community member"

Comment: I'm in favour of this as an *additional* privilege if the team can implement it relatively easily, but wouldn't want it to be the meat of it.

Comment: @Aarobot, agreed. I'm surprised that they haven't implemented it already for all users.  I don't see reasons not to.  I can't believe that it would be too terribly difficult.

Comment: I'd rather have this as a 5k rep :)

Answer (score 2):

Possibilities:

- [Inline flag counts just like close votes currently are](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55235/inline-flags-just-like-close-votes)
- [Remove the limit on duplicates they can close](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56817/can-we-prevent-some-of-the-low-quality-questions-from-entering-our-system/56829#56829)
- Give them the ability to vote to delete 10 posts per day.

Answer (score 2):

Moderators on the site get a cute little icon next to their name, 20K+ should get some sort of visual indicator.  This could scale well too  (Color, shape, etc).

(I know this is just a "fun" thing -- it has no functional purpose -- but aren't badges just fun too?)

Answer (score 1):

Let 20k+ users' votes to close **as duplicate** (not for the other close reasons) count twice  or even thrice, so that two 20k+ users are enough to dupe-close a question.

Comment: -1, duplicate voting is already misused, I feel. The fact you misnomed the " __exact__ duplicate" close reason proves my point :)

Comment: @radp I disagree. There may be frivolous duplicate votes, but all in all, the number of unclosed real duplicates overshadows them any time of the week

Comment: @Pekka That's because searching for duplicates is a bitch :) Many times it occurred to me I _knew_ there was a exact duplicate from ages ago but just couldn't find it. Once one _does_ find it, there's chat for coordination.

Comment: @radp I agree with your first sentence, but what I mean is that a dupe is identified, but doesn't gain enough dupe votes because the question falls off the front page so quickly. But maybe that gets better now with the "interesting" tab

Comment: @Pekka, I'm not sure. Bad questions get huge penalties on the interesting tab, which makes it them easy to ignore and tough to handle. That's why my sorting proposals were focused on merely giving bonuses on interesting questions, regardless of their quality :) That said, rallying for moderation support on chat is what I'd do.

Comment: @radp that adds too much hassle to the process IMO. People don't necessarily want to get involved in chat discussions. I think we have too many unclosed dupes, and this would be a good way to battle them

Comment: I was going to suggest this myself - some questions in niche areas fail to reach the required number of votes to be closed as a dupe.

Answer (score 1):

Someone needs to watch what users with new 10K rights are doing, so should 20K users see a list of actions being taken by new 10K users and be able to contact these new 10K users to guide them?

Maybe each new 10K user should be monitored by 2 or 3 20K users.

Comment: Nice idea, but the biggest jumps in responsibility lies between 2000 and 3000 (editing and closing). So if there need te be mentors it need to be earlier. And its still no guarantee that each 10K+ user act according the community.

Comment: The only new action that 10k users get is deletion/undeletion, which is pretty basic and already tracked by the 10k tools. Everything else they get is mostly reporting and tracking features, while everything they do was earned earlier. At 10k reputation they're probably less necessary to watch than users who are new to those abilities (like the newly 3k users as @Gamecat mentions).

Answer (score 1):

Give 20k trusted users more ability to help cleanup *Closed As Duplicate* questions.

Being able to change the *close as duplicate* link, so that it would point to a real canonical question would be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

The ability to put a bounty on someone else's question, spending only a fraction of the reputation it would normally take.

For example, when you saw a question that you really wanted to help, you could spend 50 of your own reputation to give that question a +250 point bounty.

This would allow 20k users to shower a little bit of extra attention on highly deserving questions.

Comment: If you have 20k does it really matter if you give 50 or 250? And what's up with the inflation that might lend to the system?

Comment: If you've got 20K rep does spending it on a bounty really matter?

Comment: Darn you @drachenstern!

Comment: well you made a good point. I can delete mine if you want to compose a better retort.

Comment: @drachentern. I don't think that inflation is really applicable here. Every upvote introduces either 5 or 10 rep into the system that just comes out of nowhere. likewise, every downvote removes 3 points that just goes nowhere. It's not really a real economy to begin with and I don't see a problem with that.

Comment: @aaronasterling ~ But they're trying to get people to close old questions and encouraging bounty giving to do so. I just see it as a way to feed inflation to those in the 5k - 15k slots. Maybe it's just me. I also don't think that a 1:5 ratio makes a big difference to 20k+ holders. Either they will or they won't give bountys

Comment: If you look at the stats. High rep users barely use the bounty feature, they are really competitive and giving up 50 rep, strangely, is not something they like to do. How about 1 free 50 bounty a week, could that work?

Comment: we'd have to watch for bounty rings, of course

Comment: Instead of this, leave the system as is, just remove the parts that suck: The 24-hour waiting period before you can award a bounty, and the limit of one bounty at a time. That would make the system really work.

Comment: I love giving bounties to random, unanswered questions.  I don't mind laying down 500 rep if anyone needs it (in fact, I was thinking of starting a chat room for it).  I'd much prefer @Pekka's idea so I can throw down a few k of rep for several questions at once.

Comment: In my mind, the main argument against this is that it gives 20k+ users the possibility to "print money", so to speak. Seeing as the likelihood is huge that another 20k+ will successfully answer the question and cash in the bounty, this will create the impression of high-reputation users feeding each other, whether it's justified or not. I think that is harmful for the community as a whole. Bounties should come from your own pocket.

Comment: @Pekka ~ So I'm not the only one seeing the potential for abuse to cause higher level inflation?

Comment: @drachenstern yes, although I'm rather concerned about the fact that only a small group can cause it. But this is an interesting view: Stack Overflow has a currency that *is backed by good questions and answers*. At least indirectly, with all the shortcomings of the voting system.

Answer (score 0):

The ability to get moderator powers for reps/20k hours every week.

- You cannot moderate questions you asked and/or answered and/or have an active bounty for.
- If you moderate a question, you cannot answer it until your mod powers expire.
- Once in moderator mode, you stay in moderator mode until your mod time runs out.
- Unused mod time is lost and *not* saved up for the following week.

I'm against adding new features above 10k reputation because it takes a *lot* of time for a SE site to get even just one 20ker. Having 20k-rep-only votes makes such a privilege useless for SE sites for a long time. Super User only has **four** 20kers, to name one of those young sites (the fifth is just 700 rep short, however.)

Comment: If some of the captchas sound inspired by Slashdot, it's because they are.

Answer (score -1):

The ability to award extra rep or a badge to users who make some kind of great contribution, kind of like the Wikipedia [Barnstar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Barnstars) idea.

**Advantage** (at least of rep) is that it is completely scalable (e.g. 200 rep awards for 20K users, 300 rep for 30K etc.).

**Disadvantage** because it is subjective some people who don't get these awards may ask, "Hey, what about me? That's not fair" and it may create a bad atmosphere.

Comment: Also, the amount would need to be well thought out. Too much rep floating around would cause the value of it to decrease.

Answer (score -5):

Is there a way to allow 20K users to contribute to the **code** of the SO sites? I mean develop a new feature or implement some of the existing feature requests?

I'm not sure how you'd do that (since it is not open source) but I could see them creating optional add-ons.

Add-ons could be: things for easier formatting, for making database queries, for "pimping" your view or avatar, etc.

Then they could earn further rep each time the add-ons are used (for the inevitable 30K bonus).

This idea needs a lot of work, I know.

Comment: Besides needing a lot of work, why would you limit it to 20k users?

Comment: @Juan Manuel - it doesn't have to be 20K per se, but two advantages are: 1. someone with 20K has a better idea of what makes a useful add-on than someone with less, because they understand the community better and 2. prestige.

Answer (score -7):

How 'bout a 20K-only chatroom?  By the time you get to 20K, you've probably interacted several times with a few other high-rep (frequent) users and it would nice to have a place to get to know them in a different setting with less noise from occasional users.  For scaling points you could add rooms at other thresholds as well (50K, 100K, and the private Jon Skeet-only room, where he receives new answers directly from God).

The danger here is this would pull these users out of more public chat rooms.

Comment: I want to upvote for the Jon Skeet joke, but I don't agree with the suggestion.  So torn!

Comment: Would this upper-crust lounge also include personal servants?

Comment: Because chat is just so extremely populated right now...

Answer (score -7):

They can cast multiple up\down votes.

E.g. Ability to cast one more +1 for every additional 15,000 points above 20,000 and -1 with a similar penalty.

I do believe in equality, but these guys are supposed to be the most experienced\enlightened programmers and hence I think should have the ability to nudge some things in the direction that they think appropriate.

I was thinking of an implicit bonus\penalty for every vote they cast, but I guess it's better that they have the discretion to decide whether or not to.

Comment: No, no, no, no.  This has been proposed, like, 500 times already in different forms.  Just having a high reputation doesn't guarantee higher expertise, especially in unfamiliar areas/tags.  A high reputation is the result of *effort* and not necessarily *expertise*.  There's a *huge* difference and the voting system absolutely needs to recognize that difference.

Comment: Terrible idea.  High rep opinions should not be worth 2 votes.

Comment: I do believe in equality too, but if you have 20k rep you're more equal than others.

Answer (score -18):

Increase daily reputation cap by 10.

Comment: And the rich get richer...

Answer (score -30):

Allow 20k users to see who downvoted their questions/answers, so they can call people out. =)

Comment: Oh when I reach 20k, there'll be a reckoning for this!

Comment: Combine this with [letting them suspend users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69989/propose-a-new-20k-reputation-privilege/69993#69993) and watch the fun begin