# Question asking causes a problem

Tags: support, asking-questions, post-ban

When I try to ask a question, I receive the message:

> Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
>
> Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account.

And strangely when I logged in on Ubuntu everything was fine.
What's the problem?

Comment: There are numerous posts about the error message you're seeing; see [these questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Sorry%2C+we+are+no+longer+accepting+questions+from+this+account.). (Not voting to close, though, because of the second half of your question.)

Comment: You can't ask new, instead improve the quality of previous posts

Comment: @random but look at the guy's contributions. How are they bad enough to justify a blocking?

Comment: @Rejoice It's possible he had other posts that are now deleted

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56817/can-we-prevent-some-of-the-low-quality-questions-from-entering-our-system/60294#60294

Comment: @Michael yeah. I would really like to be able to see deleted posts

Comment: @Rejoice [20k ability](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69989/propose-a-new-20k-reputation-privilege)?

Comment: @Michael good idea! It's probably too late to make a dent there anymore, but I'll add it nevertheless.

Comment: There's no deleted post. If I wanted to delete I would delete that -7 post.

Comment: My account has been banned from asking questions again for the 4th time ... Stack need to do something about this ... its irritating

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're logged in as a different account on your Ubuntu box than on your Windows box, and the account you're logged in as on the Windows box has been banned.

Comment: My username and reputation number and all other things on Ubuntu are the same as Windows. Except that I cannot ask. In addition, If it is banned why I can log in?

Comment: @kvphxga: Banned from asking questions isn't necessarily the same thing as banned outright. But it's odd if you're seeing the same reputation etc...

Comment: This is again a case where - judging from the content visible  - the "bad questions" filter has blocked a user who doesn't really seem to deserve it (There is one -7 spike but the overall quality of contributions looks pretty decent). I'm all for blocking users who ask bad questions, but I hope the team know what they're doing here

Comment: My account has been banned from asking questions again for the 4th time ... Stack need to do something about this ... its irritating