# Encourage new tag wikis by reducing requirements to create a tag wiki when there is none

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, tag-wiki, tag-badges

It seems to me that there are a lot of tags with no wikis. I think that tag wikis are a nice feature and it'd be great to have more of them.

I propose that when there is no tag wiki at all we allow even users who are not Top 20 Answerers and who do not have the bronze badge in the tag to create a new tag wiki providing they have enough reputation. It seems to me that the reputation restriction is sufficient to deter vandalism. We could even raise it to say 5,000. This should allow for the creation of a lot more tag wikis.

Also, when you get a new tag Badge for a tag that has no wiki, the message informing you of your new badge should also encourage you to create a wiki for the tag if there isn't one already.

Comment: See also [this suggestion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69989/propose-a-new-20k-reputation-privilege/69992#69992) for allowing all 20k users arbitrary tag wiki edit privileges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done, anybody can suggest creating or changing any tag wiki

Comment: I am not seeing this behavior.  For me, after proposing a tag-wiki for [meta-tag:oy], I can't edit it to clean it up.  I still see 'To edit this wiki, you must have at least 20000 reputation.;

Answer (score 6):

I suspect this is a big part of the proposal: *Also, when you get a new tag Badge for a tag that has no wiki, the message informing you of your new badge should also encourage you to create a wiki for the tag if there isn't one already.*

To me, this is a no-brainer... People are of good will when they just earned a badge, aren't they?

Answer (score 4):

Scenario:

> JoeUser has insufficient in-tag rep to edit a tag wiki, but enough to create one from scratch. He writes a simple wiki, submits it, and *then* notices a glaring typo...

Now what?

Comment: What happens now if a user is a top 20 answerer and then later loses his Top 20 status? I think that anyone who once edited a tag wiki should be able to do so always. Another alternative would be to let him edit it until a bronze or or top 20 user edits it.