# Are questions that are closed visible to visitors from search engines?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, google, search-engine

I know that questions that are closed are not allowed to answer further. But are these questions visible to outside world? I mean are these questions can be searched from search engines like Google?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they are still visible to search engines as long as they aren't also deleted.

<sub>[I made a request to change this behaviour and hide them recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161804/dont-index-closed-questions-non-duplicate-for-search-engines), but that hasn't been acted on yet</sub>