# Closed Question that appear useful, and searchable

Tags: discussion

Okay, this is starting to get /really/ tiring. I continue to come across "Not Constructive" and "Not a Question" closed questions that are on top of Google Results, and just so happen to be asking(and answering) exactly what I was thinking about.

I understand the 'intent' of closing questions that could be deemed 'not SO quality', but [This Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760070/jquery-phone-number-format) It is asking a simple question(I have X, and need Y)

I'm seeing it en mass in the Symfony and Javascript tags.

When you google a problem, and the result is a "Closed" question that answers the problem, it makes SO look bad, IMHO.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161804/dont-index-closed-questions-non-duplicate-for-search-engines. My question is rather than not closing "bad" questions wouldn't it be better to push them further down search engine's rankings?

Comment: I'm perfectly fine with pushing down their likelihood of ranking, but for ones that /do/ provide answers and a question that can be answered, They just shouldn't have been closed in the first place.

Comment: @Rixius, here's what you should ask yourself -- if that question were asked right now, would it be closed on SO?  I would say the answer to that for the question to which you linked is *yes*.  It is either **a)** a shopping question asking for a plugin or **b)** asking for a regex without having put in any effort into determining what that regex should be.

Comment: @KirkWoll I can see that. I'm not sure "Not Constructive" is the way to explain that, but I can see the reason for it to be closed. And that's another issue itself. I'll go with Madara's Answer, and basically just queue up questions that I want to return to and evaluate when I have time.

Comment: How is changing `2124771000` into `212-477-1000` a great question? And why would anyone need a plugin for that?!

Comment: Well, clearly a jQuery plugin is needed for such a complex task. I propose calling it `JennyJenny.js`.

Comment: I'm done, Madara Answered the Question perfectly, laying out the sort of things that can be done in similar situations. At this point its just more people coming in and wasting both of our time(mine and the person feeling the need to comment on a solved issue).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you think the question should not be closed, you have several options, apply those *in order*:

1. If you have more than 3K, vote it for reopening.
2. Talk about it in the appropriate chat rooms.
3. Flag it for reopening by a moderator.
4. Start a meta post with it. Tag it [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question), and explain why you think it should be reopened (hint, "it's in the first position in Google" isn't a good excuse).

We can't help exactly unless we know the exact questions, and take note that we would still evaluate them to see if they deserve reopening.

Comment: I'm just coming across questions while working on a project that I'm in, and it's frustrating. It just feels like the moderation is being to gung-ho about shutting down posts that it shouldn't be. I'll start bookmarking them and when I have time doing 2-4.

Answer (score 2):

Madara's answer offers your options here. I have some other information, because I am the one who flagged this post, last year, for the moderators to act on.

The reason was simple: in my flag, I pointed out that the question was 'attracting spam'. It essentially begs for a list of products as answers. And it got a couple answers that were deleted for 'fulfilling' that purpose.

Additionally, it had already gotten 'better' answers... that told how to do what was being asked. My hope was after being closed, the question would have been reworded by the asker or someone else, or someone would point out it was a duplicate of something else.

Basically, the question did - and still does need help. It has still not gotten that help.

If you edit it not to be a 'show me the spam' post, I would vote to reopen it myself.