# Could this question be changed and reopened?

Tags: discussion

This question was closed, but it looks like it was done more for pedantic reasons.

[What should my Objective-C singleton look like?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-should-my-objective-c-singleton-look-like)

The question is really:

How do I create a singleton in Objective-C? Is my solution here appropriate:

They unfortunately phrased it as an opinion question, but it is:

1. Really a functional question: How can this be done?
2. May change as the language evolves (some answers could already be modified for ARC)

Comment: It's not really a functional question of "how can this be done?", because the asker has provided a way to do it in the question. It's "can this be done better?", which is pretty [CodeReview.SE]-y and more of a style thing, which can border on unconstructiveness. (Or, in short: what George Stocker said in his comment on the question.)

Comment: Why would this need to be reopened? It's still there, answered 26 times, unlikely to be deleted, but ultimately better for CR if it were asked now.

Comment: @minitech Just take their answer out of the question and put it in an answer as per Q&A style this site supports. It is a question with multiple answers, as are many questions on SO.

Comment: @Bart See part two, already some answers could be updated for ARC.

Comment: Closely related, maybe dupe (its subject is that very question): [Suggestions for editing old not constructive question into constructiveness](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141006/suggestions-for-editing-old-not-constructive-question-into-constructiveness-so)

Comment: @JoshCaswell Yup. Guess I was late to the party.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general if you think there's a real, answerable question lurking in there, then edit the question to bring it out.

If you have 3,000+ reputation vote to reopen, but even if you haven't the fact you have edited it will add it to the `/review/reopen` queue where other people can review your edits and vote to reopen if they agree with you.

In this specific case it's probably not worth reopening the question even if you could edit it - which you can't because it's locked. Migrating is not an option either because it's too old (by a long way) and (even it could be migrated) it has effectively been answered so migrating it to Code Review wouldn't benefit anyone.

Comment: If you think the question needs editing and reopening then edit _first_. Give the people who view it in the reopen queue something good to look at and a reason why it should be reopened.

Comment: So I should edit it even though I can't? That doesn't seem like a great solution in this case, though I respect the principle in general.

Comment: Actually, here we go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568935/how-do-i-implement-an-objective-c-singleton-that-is-compatible-with-arc this basically solves the issue.

Comment: @BenFlynn - And Colin's answer on the original question is the same as Nick's there. The original question was becoming something of a problem, because it had six duplicated answers (now deleted), some follow-on questions asked in answers, a bunch of wrong answers, and more kept getting added to it. It was becoming troublesome to maintain, which tends to be the result of more open-ended questions. As you can see, a more specific, targeted question ended up not having that same problem. The historical lock guarantees none of that content will be lost even though the question is closed.

Comment: @BradLarson Thanks Brad. Makes sense.