# Have all the answerers misunderstood the question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Here's a related topic which partially helps me figure out my next step, but on the other hand  it doesn't fully answer my question so it is not quite a duplicate: [Exit strategies for "chameleon questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)

I am writing in relation to [Dynamically Create Dynamic Arrays in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18978839/dynamically-create-dynamic-arrays-in-vba/18979499#18979499)

I don't expect you to be able to provide an answer to the above linked question. Merging two given answers and the +1 comments from the TOP user in the [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) and [excel-vba](/questions/tagged/excel-vba) tags should be enough to make conclusions.

After both questions were posted and up voted the OP showed up leaving a comment

> Thank you for your answer mehow as always, and thank you too Mike
> Woodhouse, not quite what I was hoping for, but both very clever
> nevertheless I think. I´m going to update my question and see if that
> creates an answer that I´m happy with. – steinbitur

That is really nice of him to thank us both for the answers. He's being nice and polite. I can't say a bad word.

but...

the question itself has been interpreted by 2+ people who decided to give an answer. Doesn't this make it clear enough for others too? The question has been given 2 different answers with alternative ways of solving the original problem.

The question, as it stands, is a reliable and good source of information.

What I am afraid is going to happen now, its that the OP will come back and change the meaning of his question and maybe narrow and localize the question to his specific problem.

It seems to me that the original problem has been solved and I can't really blame nobody for the misunderstanding but the OP. If the question made sense to 2 people then why change it?

I honestly pray this will not happen because everything looks spot on as it stands. Spot on, with one exception - the misunderstanding between the OP and the answerers.

I would feel really bad saying something like: *your original problem should be solved now, if you have another question consider asking a new one.*

What would be the right thing to do in this case? ( please, exclude *waiting* as an answer )

## Update

I have added a comment per @Gnat's suggestion

> the problem as you stated it originally should be solved now, if you
> have another question consider asking a new one, based on what you
> have learned in this question. Try to avoid changing your question in
> a way that would invalidate existing good answers

Let's leave it there for now and see what happens

## Update2!

The OP *sees my(@gnats) point* and will ask another question. So leaving a constructive suggestion was a  really good idea.

Comment: "Not quite what I was looking for" sounds like he has an idea and was hoping to see that idea confirmed. Something that should have been part of the question, if that is the case.

Comment: I wouldn't feel bad saying like _the problem as you stated it originally should be solved now, if you have another question consider asking a new one, based on what you have learned in this question. Try to avoid changing your question in a way that would invalidate existing good answers_

Comment: I agree with @gnat here definitely; if the edit changes the meaning of the question, invalidating your answers (as it seems it will), it should definitely remain as it is, and a new question asked.

Comment: @Oded I think the idea is the code he provided. It is impossible to do dynamically name variables without workarounds. That's mentioned in the answers so I do not understand why he still feels so down :/

Comment: @gnat didn't I say I was going to copy-paste it:)? I have given it a try

Comment: @mehow - True. My point was that the question was incomplete, as far as what the OP was expecting. But as it is, it got good answers. The OP seems to have a _different_ question in mind, which should indeed by a different question. Commenting something to the tune of "Adding additional constraints to this question would completely change it and invalidate the answers people worked on to help with the issue as described. Please ask a new question with all the relevant details, so this question can stand as is with the answers as they are".

Comment: I agree with you Oded and gnat. +1 Andrew. That makes 4 of us who wouldn't feel bad for leaving a pre-caution comment. That extra safety before the OP comes back and edits his question.

Comment: @gnat you had a good idea. The OP has seen the comment and will ask another question. well done. If you want to post your comment as an answer Ill accept it

Comment: @mehow [there you go](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/198126/165773 "re-posted as an answer")

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I wouldn't feel bad saying like:

> the problem as you stated it originally should be solved now, if you have another question consider asking a new one, <sup>1</sup> based on what you have learned here. Try to avoid changing your question in a way that would invalidate <sup>2</sup> existing good <sup>3</sup> answers

<sup>1</sup> *asking a new question, based on what was learned in existing one* -- this reasoning mostly follows what was discussed in [Exit strategies for "chameleon questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions?lq=1)

<sup>2</sup> *avoid invalidating answers* -- my understanding is that current community preference is for generally trying to avoid such an invalidation, up to the point of [completely locking substantial edits to question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/144787/165773).

<sup>3</sup> *good answers* - word "good" here is to stay on a safe side. Per my observations, although general preference is in favor of "locking" question edits to keep even answers that are not so good, there are still cases when edits invalidating *obviously, blatantly low quality* answers are considered OK.