# Improve the "recently deleted" tool

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, 10k-tools, recently-deleted

The "recently deleted" 10k tool is too limited:

- it only includes a fixed number of deleted posts (45 apparently?)
- it only displays posts in a certain time-span (haven't seen anything older than 1h)
- it includes spam posts etc., making it hard to filter out deletions for review
- it doesn't allow to distinguish between questions & answers
- it doesn't show votes, views or anything to quickly filter out what might be review-worthy
- ...

While I feel that actually a better deletion review process would be needed, with the current "recently deleted" list there effectively is only a case-by-case review process:
As soon as deleted posts drop off the very short list, they are basically gone and only users who have the question id handy for one reason or the other can effectively get to it.

A good start would be to:

- make an unlimited or less limited view of deletions
- make it more easy to filter by including post type (Q or A) and possibly votes/views in some table format