# Losing reputation when question less than 60 days old is deleted

Tags: feature-request, reputation, deleted-questions

**I know** we lose reputation when we give an answer and the questions gets deleted.

**Why** do we lose reputation when the question is deleted?

> First, if you've contributed something worthwhile to the site, you should keep the reputation for that even if it eventually gets deleted. “Worthwhile” here is defined as,
>
> - A score of 3 or greater
> - Visible on the site for at least 60 days

These are the requirements to keep your points if the questions gets deleted. **What? 60 days?**

I had an answer with 20 upvotes, so I guess it was "somehow" helpful to someone. But a few days after, the OP decides that even if he had accepted my answer, he would delete the question. Why should I lose 200 reputation because of this? Yes, I guess I should lose the accept bonus and the OP's vote if he/she did vote, but I should not have to pay for the choice to remove the question since I earned my reputation fair and square.

This is, in my opinion, a very bad design. The day count should be lowered a *lot* and even ruled out if the OP accepts the answer.

---

Someone pointed out OP can't delete the question if it has upvoted answer. Well, no matter who deleted it, I don't believe I should lose my reputation.

[The question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160166/add-year-visitor-badge/160167#160167). Like I said I understand I can lose point given by the OP, but I spend a lot of time around here asking / answering question and I always found that the site is well balanced and stuff, but this is really bad.

Comment: OP cannot delete a question if it has upvoted answers

Comment: If someone asks a completely off-topic easy fun question and ten people answer it, they'll probably get a lot of upvotes (based on historical anecdotes because people seem to upvote funny stuff too).  But, should they keep that reputation for an off-topic answer?  Doesn't that devalue the "reputation means we trust you" system?

Comment: @Troyen I totally understand that and woudn't be asking this question if my answer was 1- funny, 2- out off topic. if the OP doesn't look around before posting his question and my answer seems so obvious that it looks funny its not my fault. In here, all question have an answer that seems obvious to someone. We get this kind of request here all the time and this is not a question that always get deleted. The OP was just mad he got downvoted so he asked for it to be deleted. Not because the question or my answer was wrong or funny

Comment: Fun fact: you used to lose reputation for posts deleted regardless of their age. This change [was a concession](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/) to a bigger problem of old, highly-upvoted questions getting deleted after they became off-topic or otherwise inappropriate on the site over the years.

Comment: @AnnaLear you really think that someone should loose is earned reputation because someone decided to delete the question ? I still say bad design. Why don't I get my reputation only 60 days after the question has been answered since it's not worth anything before that ?

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk It depends. I don't think there's a perfect solution there. There are questions where people post joke non-answers that absolutely SHOULD lose reputation from upvotes those "answers" got before the question got deleted. The best advice I can give is not to worry about reputation too much. There's always more to be gained from answering questions that aren't likely to get closed and/or deleted.

Comment: reputation is lost because this is **fair**. By implication, you may assume that losing reputation from `+3/60d` questions would be fair, too... and that is correct. Reputation for `+3/60d` is kept for reasons having very little to do with fairness, see eg [Community-led deletionism: a protocol for sanity](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124439/165773) and [Reputation and Historical Archives](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/)

Comment: 60 reputation lost for *each* of [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14951211/swap-2-numbers-without-3rd-variable/14951289#14951289) [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207227/checking-string-for-large-amount-of-different-incremental-values/15207365#15207365) in the last 2 weeks (and it's not like I've got 100k reputation, ever bit matters). This makes me negative about the site. Worst of all is that neither were particularly off topic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'll share my opinion on this matter.

Basically, getting upvotes for a post (might be a question or an answer) doesn't always mean it's really good, or more often doesn't really mean it fits in the site. *The post shouldn't be there in the first place*.

For example suppose someone now post a question on Stack Overflow like "What was your most fun project using C or C++?" and suppose some users are going to like it and upvote. It will obviously be closed and deleted sooner than later, so why let the user keep the reputation that he shouldn't gain in the first place?

On the other hand, if a post got non trivial positive score (1 or 2 might be just robo reviewers) and "survive" long enough then most likely it means the post was actually good and contributed to the community; even if it somehow get deleted (e.g. not relevant anymore) its author deserves the rep.

Comment: @Rathony no. Only if the score of the post was 3 or more and it was deleted after 60 days, the reputation will be preserved. Also, those are 60 days of the post being visible, meaning if someone posts an answer, gets 3 upvotes in one hour, deletes the answer, then undelete it 60 days later, the reputation will **not** be preserved. (to prevent abusing the system.)