# Problem with Stack Overflow reputation league

Tags: support, reputation-leagues

I was quite impressed when I saw this week's Stack Overflow leaderboard:

[image]

But the user's reputation activity doesn't quite match:

[image]

What's going on?

Comment: @animuson thanks for correcting the tag, it certainly looked like a bug at the time.

Comment: This is my first question on meta.stackexchange so if someone could explain the downvotes I'd appreciate it.

Comment: The first thing to know about this site's voting is that it's capricious: people tend to vote rather quickly. I don't really like that, but it is how it is. *sigh*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He had an extremely popular post on Stack Overflow.

Unfortunately, the question was closed, and [ultimately deleted by a moderator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/384382/1197934), and the leagues haven't caught up yet.

Comment: I guess the +5160 must have come from the question temporarily being undeleted...

Comment: It had over 500 upvotes, but max rep for one day is 200.  Might be something stuck in the calculator, maybe.

Comment: If it had been awarded 5160 reputation over the course of many days and it was deleted, and then undeleted that would account for the +5160 rep change.

Comment: Rep lost from post deletions is not included in the reputation league, as the per-time rep in the league [excludes "private" reputation changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141628/why-is-my-total-reputation-less-than-my-monthly-reputation/141691#141691) such as deleted posts. So the reputation lost from having that post deleted will never be cleared from that number.

Answer (score -2):

You should check if this does actually decrease his reputation. I'm new to Stack Exchange, but most sites don't delete overall user points when a thread is deleted.

Comment: With a few exceptions, @The. When *old*, highly-scored posts are deleted, you get to keep the reputation. But yeah, normally, deletion of a post removes any reputation that you might have gained from it. The logic is, reputation is a score/index of your valuable contributions to this community. If a post is deleted, it is no longer providing value to this community.

Comment: @TheWanderer the reputation will be kept if only [the post is older than 60 days with a minimum of +3 score](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160450/241919).

Comment: Thread? That is a forum term. We have questions and answers here, not threads. [The Stack Exchange sites are ***not*** forums](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115) (fora?). They are [think tanks](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325681).