# Could you (moderators) stop deleting community wiki questions?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, moderators

### Problem background

This question is addressed to you, ♦ moderators. There is e.g. [this question *10k+*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/102254/960757), which is full of very useful information. It's been a community wiki with more than 17k views with 51 answers.

The question is off-topic, there's nothing to discuss, but why it was deleted ? Couldn't you just lock it as you did with a several posts around ? The biggest problem is that our community can't even undelete it because it's protected by the ♦ law.

So now it's a community wiki question, which can't be seen nor even undeleted by the community.

### Question

Could you undelete that question and let the community decide what to do with it? And if that is possible, could you lock that question to keep its content visible and as it is?

---

<sup>P.S. those reopen votes are there because of curiosity. We shall keep that question closed.</sup>

Comment: So you don't have a problem with Bo Persson, Ben Voigt, John Saunders, joran, and kapa, then?

Comment: Suggestion: focus on this question in particular, rather than community wiki posts (or moderators) in general.

Comment: @Brad, no, because they have lower privileges, so that we could undelete the question by ourselves. With that diamond delete vote we can't. That's not fair.

Comment: I find it mildly amusing that the overwhelming majority of these hidden features are documented.

Comment: How is cw relevant to any of this?

Comment: @Yannis, ok. Take it just as a question. Guys, could you stop being so pedantic, please ? Don't you just see it ? There's a useful question with lot of information which we would like to undelete because it can be useful to other people (let's call this group of people **community**). But we can't. That's all...

Comment: If you agree a question should be closed, you should also agree that it needs to be deleted.

Comment: How was the referenced question deleted last year, but [reopened 20 minutes ago](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/102254/revisions)?

Comment: @slhck, not at all. That question deserves to keep closed and to be locked. But **visible to people**!

Comment: @Michael Petrotta, because we did. There's probably a "bug". But focus on the question in particular rather than if it's reopened. We can close it again.

Comment: Hmm. No idea you could do that to a deleted question. Ok.

Comment: @slhck Not talking about this question in particular, but that a question should be closed does absolutely not mean that it also should be deleted

Comment: I agree in the sense that I would prefer to see old, hugely popular questions locked instead of deleted but I would advise you to rephrase some of your post to make it more constructive. Right now it feels a like a rant and it hides the actual problem.

Comment: I'll restate, TLama. Many community wiki questions deserve to be deleted. It's not a "get out of deletion free" card. Focus your question on this post in particular, or a specific class of posts, and you'll likely get a better response.

Comment: I should point out that, in general, [we now shy away from using binding delete votes on highly voted questions like this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124439/community-led-deletionism-a-protocol-for-sanity). The moderator who acted on this will need to comment on their reasons for casting the final vote, but I will note that the following flag was on that question: "This question serves no purpose. Of the 51 answers only 2 or 3 are actual hidden features of Delphi (assuming easter eggs can be considered features). The rest were pulled directly from the Delphi documentation."

Comment: @Brad, ok. Thanks for your support. FYI, none of the people who voted for that question's deletion has something to do with Delphi. Regards.

Comment: @TLama I don't think you have to be a Delphi programmer to be qualified to vote on Delphi questions

Comment: @BradLarson that's why I prefer _verbose_ flag messages. Challenge Programmers mods on any question they deleted per my flags, they will immediately shoot 500 chars justification, quoted straight from my message :)

Comment: @TLama The person who flagged it (which is what Brad is referring to) has quite a lot of experience in `Delphi`.

Comment: @George, ok. That's sufficient answer for me. Thanks!

Comment: DEAR MODS: SOTP BEING MEANIE-FACES. I HAT YOU BEHAVIRS

Comment: That's it mods. I'm kidnapping all your spouses and taking them to Mexico until this question is undeleted. While in Mexico, your spouse will enjoy all-inclusive meals and spa packages.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO So what you are saying is you absolutely, positively do *not* want that undeleted? ;)

Comment: Note that historical locks are only applied to questions that have an *extraordinarily* high value.  Not just questions that are "okay" or "pretty good", but content so vitally important to keep around that it's worth making an exception to the site's standards to keep around.  There are only a small handful of questions that are sufficiently valuable to warrant such locks.  It doesn't appear that this question meets that standard.

Comment: Wow. Now it has even duplicate vote of close voting related question. Have you even read this one ? It's about diamond delete vote lock!

Comment: @TLama, duplicate votes work a bit differently on meta.

Comment: @Joe, I'm having trouble to understand meta, reporting bugs (however minor they are) or even get people here (of course I'm not talking about voting, that;s what I know how works here). Sorry for that. The next time I'll be quiet.

Comment: @TLama It's a different community, really, and just like getting used to Stack Overflow it takes a little time steeping in the community to "get" meta.  But it can be worth it, if you have strong opinions on the direction of Stack Overflow.  There are many who hold views similar to yours.

Comment: @TLama There's nothing wrong with posting suggestions/questions/whatever.  *however*, you need to have a thick enough skin to survive people disagreeing with you en masse.  Most of the folks here at Meta are the most active, interested folks on SE/SO; we are here because we care a lot about how SE/SO works and is run.  As such we have strong opinions and will strongly express them.  So please keep making suggestions - just don't be defensive if they're shot down.

Comment: Also, fleshing out my duplicate comment: Duplicate votes on MSO are to some extent ways to answer/decline suggestions/show why things are how they are, rather than 'this is a precise duplicate of your question' as it would be on regular SO.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, _I don't think you have to be a Delphi programmer to be qualified to vote on Delphi questions_. So you dont have to know anything about a language to judge if a question, or an answer, may be **useful** for people programming in that language? Why not eliminate the human factor in general and delete questions randomly? Or let a robo looking for - lets say - bad spelling deleting questions? Seems even better. A effective robo could even get rid of the close vote-hump in a few hours. Content, and the understanding of the content, is appearently not an issue.

Comment: @davidkonrad Why is experience about a specific language needed to judge the quality of a question? I'm not so hung up on languages as you seem to be. You don't need to know anything about Delphi to know that this particular question is poor. It would be a poor question if you replaced Delphi with any other language.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, A typical meta straw man, after the book wrapped into a polemic question. Where did I talk about **quality**? Exactly, nowhere. I exsplicitly wrote "..may be **useful** for people programming in that language". **Usefulness** for the insider  is not equal to the outsiders personal impression of "quality". Quality is abstract and can be measured in many ways. One of those ways is usefulness, and on a QA site for programmers, usefulness for those who actually is programming in a particular language obviously must be thé most important sign of quality.

Comment: "_You don't need to know anything about Delphi to know that this particular question is poor_." - It is nessecary in general, when a Q has 10k of views, a lot of upvotes etc, knowledge to the language is mandatory. If you not feel a robo can do a better job, of course. "_It would be a poor question if you replaced Delphi with any other language_". Again polemic. If it is a specific question about Delphi, it would be very low quality for any other language; if it is about general programming just with Delphi in focus, its not a question about Delphi - so this last "argument" is nothing worth.

Comment: @davidkonrad The question wasn't closed because of its lack of usefulness. Although as it happens, it is neither useful nor of reasonable quality.

Comment: @davidkonrad And what's more it is categorically possible, indeed easy, for a non Delphi expert to make the usefulness judgement. The question simply fails to ask a specific question. It's just pot luck if the answers contain the solution to the problem that a future visitor might be facing. A good question might be, "What keyboard shortcut can I use to invoke X?" But that's not what is asked here. It looks to me that you are not capable of assessing the usefulness of this question. But I don't see that others will necessarily be incapable of assessing it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the record, I cast that vote to delete because my conclusion was the same as Brad noted a flagging user had cast. It really was not exceptional in any way, except it did have a halfway decent view count. The answers were mostly just random junk, really.

But the content was not all that great at all, and it was not even a highly-voted post.

I don't know if I would have deleted that question *today*; my own opinion has wandered a bit more toward being cautious with that kind of deletion.

I know it can't be community-undeleted, but if lots of people want it restored, I'd be OK doing that. It's really a "meh" for me, at this point.

<sup>Also; Be careful about assuming that lack of participation in a tag equates to lack of knowledge of the related topic. For example, your assumptions about my lack of experience with Delphi may seem justified by my complete lack of participation in the related tags, but not entirely by reality. I am passingly familiar with it and have done some tiny work with it... also, don't forget that knowledge of the topic is not always required for such things.</sup>

Comment: Thanks to animuson! @Andrew, sorry if it sounded somehow offensive to you. It wasn't meant to be (to anyone). It just drove me mad when we couldn't undelete it by ourselves. Thanks for your offer anyway!

Comment: @TLama Oh, no. There was nothing offensive in what you posted. I should probably have worded my closing note a little more clear in that regard. It's a common - and not altogether unfounded - assumption that lack of activity in a tag suggests lack of knowledge of the related technologies.

Comment: I disagree that deleting questions like this makes StackOverflow a better site. I think that this has basically been a sideways, backwards move.

Answer (score 10):

> Could you stop deleting community wiki questions?

What you should be specifically asking for here is a "Historical Lock" which allows the question to remain visible, but not open for further activity:

[What is a historical lock, and what is it used for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for)

I don't believe this question meets the requirements for such a lock, but that is somewhat subjective.

Your best bet is to explain how this question meets the requirements for a historical lock, rather than attacking moderators or others about a question which is obviously not appropriate for the site.

Note that these days merely meeting the basic requirements isn't enough - a question has to show *significant* value to the community to be eligible.