# New Policy Is Draining My Affection For Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

You might think the new policy is the bee's knees, but personally I find that my reputation is going backwards by the day with each question deleted.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518688/what-experience-should-the-ideal-software-manager-have/518709#518709

It was asked and answered in good faith a long time ago; now someone has made an arbitrary decision that it no longer fits the profile.  I think the decisions are subjective.  I doubt that any of the top ten reputations have seen any decrease.  It seems unfair to me.

Yes, I'm sure that lame attempts at humor will be greatly appreciated here.  My point is that the question is *more than three years old*.  This was removed after all this time by the arbitrary decision of a moderator, one that's probably a newly appointed to the office.

I could understand it if it was part of the new algorithm to recalculate immediately if a question is deleted.  That makes sense.  It's the culling of old answers, when such a harvesting has never been necessary before, that is objectionable.

Fine, consider this deleted.  My sense of community has been diminished.  I'll ask the moderator to remove it.  They seem anxious to remove answers submitted in good faith; let's see if they'll respond to a direct request.

Comment: The ideal software manager should be a unicorn with freehand circles.

Comment: I don't think the decision is arbitrary

Comment: Then you're admitting that all the other moderators have done a poor job for the three years that the question remained?

Comment: Robert Harvey is not exactly a new-comer as far as i know...

Comment: How long has he been a moderator?  His tenure at SO is just over two years, so his moderator status is younger than that.

Comment: Related to [Change the way really old questions are deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124309/2509).

Comment: I don't get what you are saying about the top ten users. Are you insinuating the deletion of questions is somehow steered so the top ten users' reputations are spared?

Comment: @dufymo: He has been a moderator for [more than a year](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/welcome-our-new-trilogy-moderators-for-2011/) now.

Comment: Old things get dug up, found off-topic under rule changes that occured since they were last seen, and deleted all the time. I don't see the problem here.

Comment: @duffymo There are thousands of questions on SO that need closing and deleting. Moderators aren't supposed to do everything. They might close or delete a question that doesn't belong on SO if they happen to see it, but it's primarily the job of **us, the community** to cull the bad content. You have 10k rep on SO; you should be participating in the cleanup efforts.

Comment: I hadn't thought about exercising that power, but I'll pay more attention to it in the future, Giles.

Comment: "I doubt that any of the top ten reputations have seen any decrease." Plenty of questions I've answered have been deleted, and I've sometimes lost rep due to that. (Usually just the acceptance bonus, as rep from votes is usually recovered from other votes on that day, up to the rep cap. If I hadn't exceeded the rep cap on every day, I'd have lost rather more.) I'm not quite sure what your sentence was trying to imply, but if it's some element of bias, then I think the charge is ungrounded.

Comment: Considering the debate currently going on, how can this question be closed as not constructive? Isn't this a valid and relevant opinion? from a 100k+ user, even? Given how fond the MSO crew is of arguing that there's no evidence that productive users are upset with current policies, closing this seems dishonest

Comment: I believe [the great question deletion audit of 2012](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122120/the-great-question-deletion-audit-of-2012) is much more to blame than the recent "always-up-to-date reputation".

Answer (score 21):

It's not a new policy at all.

It's just that with the new so hip, so fresh accurate update of reputation changes, users are now more intimately aware of how much of their actual contributions to Stack Overflow are forum discussions or off topic.

This in accordance with the FAQ that hasn't all of a sudden changed overnight.

Comment: then it's the poor enforcement for the past three years that's at fault.

Comment: @duffy Im not sure faulting someone is constructive

Comment: I'm venting, that's all.  Right now I don't care about being constructive.

Comment: @duffy I can understand why you might be upset, but I'm not sure venting will help make changes.

Comment: I'm sure it won't.  Meta is the one possibility for venting, so that's why I'm here.

Comment: Blaming poor enforcement is fine, but I'm not sure why that leads to "I got away with it for three years, so I should keep getting away with it". There isn't a statute of limitations on low-quality posts

Comment: May I suggest that Chat is more appropriate for this, @duffymo?

Comment: Chat with whom - you, Michael?  As for getting away with it, I'm not trying to get away with anything.  I've got sufficient rep here where a drop isn't going to make a difference to me.  I wonder what someone for whom such an action might represent a 50% drop would feel.  They might not come back.  I'd ask what the harm to the forum and sense of community is.

Comment: No, not me, @duffymo. If you're looking to vent, I'd say [The Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta). But really, since you've admitted you're being purposely nonconstructive,  I was trying to find a nice way to say "stop it".

Comment: I don't think it's entirely accurate to lay the blame for this at the feet of the new rep tracking algorithms.  In reviewing my reputation history I see that there have been 11 questions that I answered deleted in the last 3 days, whereas I have to go back a year to ever see an entire month with more than one deletion in it.

Comment: @duffymo Find the person who's rep was cut in 1/2 or it didn't happen (and even then, it was *always* like that, they just didn't know until now).

Comment: @tvanfosson [Mass clean-up of career-development questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119713/mass-clean-up-of-career-development-questions) seems to be the reason for the recent increase.

Comment: I want to dislike this answer, but, I just can't.  +1