# Should "What is the best Python book for experienced programmers?" get a historical lock?

Tags: discussion, historical-lock

Should [What is the best Python book for experienced programmers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/457757/561731) get a historical lock put on it?

It is the [#1 result when searching on google](https://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=best+python+book) when searching for "best python book"

Comment: Ha - two people downvoted your question, but neither of your poll options.  Have you been trolling on Stack Overflow or something?

Comment: @AdamRackis I don't think I have. odd.

Comment: I can tell Panama posting "Should X be locked?" and then him and Rackis mocking the downvotes is going to become a daily tradition. We don't need to vote on every post you stumble across -- mod flag it if you think it should be locked, and if it gets rejected and you feel badly that it needs a lock, then go to town on meta to try and talk them into it

Comment: @Michael - mocking is a bit strong of a word.  But why are you always in such a bad mood?  It's rather off-putting.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek I was told "Bring stuff like this up on Meta and let the community vote on it." in response to flagging one for locking (hence my posts yesterday).

Comment: Setting these up as polls with answers representing yes/no responses is not going to work. Folks can already vote to close / re-open, and they can already vote on the proposal (question) itself - save *answers* for reasoned arguments for or against the proposal.

Comment: @JeremyBanks Ok then; that seems painfully inefficient when we've already elected people to handle this, but if they want to drag each one of these out into an argument then let's go for it

Comment: @Michael - excuse me, but the only person who seems to make these question argumentative is [you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126276/should-whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java-have-been-deleted/126289#comment342009_126289).  The rest of the community seems to handle these questions just fine.

Comment: @AdamRackis If we're not going to argue about the merits of locking the post or not then there's no reason to have the meta post at all -- you're assuming "argue" is a bad thing. Pretend I said "discuss" if that helps

Comment: @Michael - it's possible to *discuss* something without being argumentative.

Comment: @AdamRackis Fine, then I meant "discuss"; I didn't intend to use "argue" in a negative way, sorry. There are tons of these old posts that I try hard to ignore, and I don't look forward to meta becoming a giant list of "should we delete X" for all old high-voted questions X. If SO mods want to do that then fine, I didn't know that was their policy till now

Comment: @JeremyBanks: I declined one of your flags with: *" Negative... It fails the "practical learning" test in Jeff Atwood's "We Hate Fun Here" blog post. Post a question on Meta if you want to appeal.*" But I certainly wasn't advocating starting a debate for every one of these questions.

Comment: @Robert - Shog *did* seem to imply that this was the [proper way to resolve these issues](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126305/155403) - am I missing something?

Comment: Somebody should ask the question "Should we post meta questions about historical locks?". It's just meta enough to be awesome

Comment: @JeremyBanks: I just think people should be making better use of their flags. I saw your declined flag on the ["Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay) question, but you did the right thing; you flagged first. That question is not exactly controversial, and meta should be used only as a last resort, when flagging produces an unsatisfying result. [Shog's post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126305/155403) addresses an SO question that was repeatedly opened, closed, deleted, undeleted, etc.

Comment: @Michael - post it and I'll be the first upvote :)

Comment: @AdamRackis: Part of the reason that moderators are declining these flags is they don't want the hassle anymore; they don't want to get blamed for deleting content or framing garbage, preferring that the community decide for themselves. A moderator should only have to step in and pass judgement on a post *when it is clear that community consensus is not going to happen.*

Comment: @Robert - sure (and I don't think I flagged anything on images in DB).  Saving moderators from drama is exactly the reason I thought we should use meta questions like this.

Comment: @AdamRackis: Ah, you're right. That was Jeremy's flag. Responding to questions on meta is time-intensive for the mods.  We have open/close and delete/undelete systems that should be used to their fullest potential first, and then flags, and then Meta if all that fails.

Comment: @AdamRackis wow I have been gone for an hour, and there was so so so much debate..

Comment: Things move fast here on Meta :)

Comment: @AdamRackis here is my query on all of this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126560/155556

Comment: @Robert: Your comments here seem contradictory to me: «I just think people should be making better use of their flags...but you did the right thing; you flagged first.» «Part of the reason that moderators are declining these flags is they don't want the hassle anymore..., preferring that the community decide for themselves.» How do "flagging first" and "the community decide" go together? If we want decisions to be made by consensus, why wouldn't we make a Meta question? Isn't it best to allow more than 5 people to weigh in, voting here rather than directly for re-open/deletion?

Comment: @lulius: My position is that the community should use their voting powers to act first, and then flag. Moderators can, and do, act on flags cast against disputed questions, but they won't necessarily act if a question seems uncontroversial. If you want community discussion on an otherwise unremarkable question, by all means post it on meta. If that establishes a consensus, a mod can act based on that consensus.

Comment: @lulius: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126560

Comment: @RobertHarvey: How is a consensus (or lack thereof) determined? Are you saying that people have to *constantly* patrol question to see if they get deleted and then vote to undelete them? I thought the purpose of the lock was so that if people want it to be deleted, it has to be brought up on Meta first.

Comment: @lulius: Look at this question. The consensus seems to be that a historical lock is inappropriate at this time. See Adam Rackis' answer below, and the number of upvotes on it. Look at the number of downvotes on the question.  There are many purposes for the lock, other than the one you stated.

Comment: @NicolBolas Welcome to what I've been doing for the last few days. -_-

Comment: @RobertHarvey Interestingly, the balance was a little different before the poll options were deleted, IIRC. I don't like using votes on the question to determine action like this, because that could mean a poorly-asked question condemns another post to deletion forever.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: "Look at this question. The consensus seems to be that a historical lock is inappropriate at this time." Consensus? It's been *three hours*. A healthy percentage of MSO users have been *asleep* this entire time. Exactly *fifteen* users have voted on this question. How can you call 15 users in 3 hours a **consensus**? The worst part is that if exactly 3 more users disagree, the question will disappear from the front page, making more upvotes less likely and thereby squelching debate.

Comment: @NicolBolas: How much of everyone's time do you really want to expend on each of these questions? Should we send a private message to every community member each time one of these comes up for debate? How about a system banner?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Nice strawman, but that doesn't change the fact that you're willing to pronounce summery judgement when only three hours have passed. You could at least give the question a *day*.

Comment: @NicolBolas: You can have all the time you want. The question's not going anywhere, unless this question's publicity causes it to get deleted. But I don't see the community currently clamoring for deletion, so... Post an answer. Make your case.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: That doesn't change the fact that you claimed that "The consensus seems to be that a historical lock is inappropriate at this time," after only three hours. So the question returns to what I asked: How is a consensus (or lack thereof) determined? You keep wanting to put this on the community, but the *moderators* are the only ones who can put the lock on it. Until it gets locked, we have to play the "watch for deletion" game, which is not something I think a lot of people want to play.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Until that game is played out, I believe the historical lock is premature.

Comment: @NicolBolas: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126631/102937

Answer (score 12):

I'm guessing the main problem with this question is that book lists become outdated as soon as the ink is dry, and locked questions can't be updated—indeed, that's the whole point of *locking* them.

So essentially we'd be keeping around outdated information, without the ability to keep it more current.

It *might* be best to rip the band-aid off this one.

Comment: With this logic, the *book itself* becomes outdated and obsolete as soon as the ink is dry, therefore all books are worthless. (Come to think of it, every natural science professor I've ever had has made precisely this argument...)

Comment: @Cody: I read this answer as an argument for *re-opening* the question, thereby forestalling deletion, and thus allowing the question to remain both available and able to be updated. You could also view it as an argument for deletion I suppose - but either way, it's a strong argument against locking.

Comment: @Cody - nobody loves books [more than me](http://www.librarything.com/catalog/AdamRackis), and one of my [favorite books](http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/0199291152/) was written over 30 years ago (and is hardly obsolete).  My point was that the *list itself* will be obsolete before the ink is dry.  As the next version of Python and its various frameworks are developed, new books will be written to cover the new material.  If the question is locked, then we'll be keeping around outdated info that can't be updated.

Comment: So yeah, as @Shog says, opening the question and letting the Python guys keep the thread up to date would be one option, but I didn't think that was acceptable to the community. I figured ripping the band-aid off and deleting it would be better than locking it, since the latter would guarantee that we're keeping bad info around.  Shog: are questions like this officially off-topic?  I'd love to see the question opened and kept fresh; I just didn't think that was an option.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond the fact that this question potentially provides some useful information in its answers (however problematized that conclusion may be by the concern presented in [Adam's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126556/153008)), I think this question is worth a historical lock just by virtue of its "highly linked" status.

It's obviously a question that many users have found useful, not only useful enough to upvote, but also useful enough to link to elsewhere on the Internet. And extensively so.

One of the arguments made in favor of *creating* a historical locking system was to help prevent link rot across the web and keep Stack Exchange from "breaking the Internetz". Deleting this one outright looks like it would probably have that effect.

Comment: +1 because I hate deleting heavily linked-to posts.  I just hate that a lock would prevent the next must-read python book from being added to the thread.

Comment: IMO this is a clear case where the information should be moved into the tag wiki. No reason the "top books" can't be maintained there, and it *is* editable.