# Suggest Tag-Wiki edits?

Tags: feature-request, support, tag-wiki-excerpt, fun

So I just suggested a tag wiki for the Meta tag [oy](/questions/tagged/oy).  Admittedly poking a bit of fun at @RebeccaChernof.  It was my first such proposal.  It was accepted.  But now I can't edit it.  I did not know that the excerpt doesn't parse Markdown so the excerpt looks like a mess.  Could someone with 20K please fix it?

Would it be possible to allow suggested edits to tag-wikis?  Or is the consensus that this would generate too much spam?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rejected the excerpt edit and submitted a different one (there is no improve button for me on the Tag Wiki flags), which is still in the queue since I don't have the rep in [oy](/questions/tagged/oy) to approve it outright.

Comment: Someday when I grow up... I want to be 20k...

Comment: Turns out that even though I'm at 20k it won't give me buttons to approve or reject my own suggested tag-wiki edit.  We'll just have to wait.

Answer (score 0):

How did you manage to suggest a tag wiki edit in the first place?

Comment: There was no tag-wiki.  So I could suggest one.  I think this was [by-design](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73081)

Comment: For example: If you click on [meta-tag:tag-wiki-excerpt] note the link 'help us create it'.

Comment: @Tibbits, I reckon the [tag:oy] description is perfectly suited at the moment