# Don't show 10k users posts they can't delete in the delete tools

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, 10k-tools, vote-to-delete

Apparently, [20k users can now vote to delete answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69989/propose-a-new-20k-reputation-privilege/70009#70009). This led to a moment of confusion for me today, when I fired up the 10k tools and had links on the "delete" tab take me to answers of questions that weren't even closed, let alone accumulating delete votes.

Can the 10k tools' delete tab show only posts that 10k users can vote to delete? This specifically includes questions that have been closed for two days, and excludes answers and recently closed questions. (Or is it by design that 10kers may see which posts 20kers are voting to delete?)

Comment: Superficially related: [In the 10k tools, please hide answers that don't qualify for deletion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78911/in-the-10k-tools-please-hide-answers-that-dont-qualify-for-deletion)

Comment: If you know you can't delete, why bother checking it?

Comment: @Ivo, what are you talking about? I can delete _some_ posts: questions that have been closed for two days or more.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, I've never had access to 10k tools without being a mod as well @Popular Demand

Comment: As an FYI, I was just able to vote to delete a question that was only asked two hours ago (and closed one hour ago): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971735/identifying-the-filter .  Perhaps there are no more time limitations for deletion?

Comment: @Brad, [not for 20k users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69989/propose-a-new-20k-reputation-privilege/70044#70044) like you, there aren't. Those of us between 10k and 20k still have the old two-day waiting period in place.

Comment: @Popular - When did that restriction get relaxed?  I don't recall being able to do that, even at the 20k level.

Comment: @Brad, it was implemented at the same time as the answer-delete feature, approximately a day ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is now implemented as soon as we next deploy (dimming the ones that the current user can't vote on, but displaying them so there is a consistent view). Let me know of any problems.

Comment: Is the dimming going to be like in the dashboard? Or more like what happens with ignored questions?