# 20k early-votes-to-delete should not take effect immediately

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-delete, trusted-user

Users with 20k rep have recently received the power to [cast question deletion votes without the two day delay after closing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78977/2509) that is imposed on users with 10k rep, and [these votes take immediate effect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4983688/2509).

This poses a problem where offending users might not have time to see the comments and closing reason if questions are closed and deleted very quickly [as discussed in the comments on the original 20k power thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69989/propose-a-new-20k-reputation-privilege/70044#70044).

Deletion by regular users---even those with 20k reputation---should not take effect until a sufficient time has passed to give the original poster a chance to see what has happened, *or* the original poster should be able to *find and see* their own deleted material.

Answer (score 17):

I think #2 should be the default course of action:

> **The original poster should be able to find and see their own deleted material.**

Answer (score 4):

Note that this works for answers only!  Sub 10k users will not be able to see their deleted questions even with a direct link.

When a comment is added, that comment is sent to the post author's inbox.  If the post the comment belongs to is then deleted, the comment still lives in the author's inbox.  So, if the author clicks the link in their inbox, they will be taken to the page, and as it is their own content, they'll be able to view the deleted post as well as the comments on the post.

Comment: Ah...I hadn't thought of that. It means a user who is familiar with out system can find their deleted content, but is it obvious or discoverable enough for new users (who I would suspect post the bulk of obviously bad questions)?

Comment: Are you saying you don't think the inbox notifications are discoverable enough for a new user? I think the red number is noticeable enough to get a user to click it.  Beyond that, it just requires clicking on the item - new users can handle that surely.  (Unless I misunderstood you which is always possible.)

Comment: Perhaps I'm fretting too much. I guess we'll see complaints on meta if it is a really problem, and no complaints implies no problem.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this was fixed and it doesn't do that anymore

Comment: Last I checked, sub-10k users couldn't view their own deleted questions even if they had the URL. Has that been changed?

Comment: @mmyers hmm I'm not sure.  Is this only valid for answers then?

Comment: The only reason it works is because the Global Inbox doesn't track the current state of the comment, only the state at the time of messaging. So you keep the comment in the inbox because at the time the comment was posted, the post was live. Now, you'll get a link whether it was an answer or a question, but as @mmyers states the question link will be invalid to sub-10k users because they cannot visit their questions.

Comment: @mmyers: you're correct... I'd forgotten all about that.