# Delete link missing

Tags: support, 10k-tools, vote-to-delete

After the last monster recalc took me below 20k I should still have had the 10k ability to delete things.

I went to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87956/is-there-any-institute-or-program-i-can-rely-on-to-improve-my-hr-skills-closed) to cast a delete vote, and found that even though I'm still over 10k the `delete` link didn't appear.  Note that in the `delete` tab of the 10k tools it shows as having two delete votes (as of the occurrence, as per this pic).

[image]

[image]

**EDIT:**  As Grace Note pointed out, in February (2011) they [changed it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69989/propose-a-new-20k-reputation-privilege/70044#70044) so 20ks could delete posts immediately instead of waiting for 2 days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Protect questions is a [15000 privilege](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/protect-questions), not 20000.

Consequently, you currently can't vote to delete that post because as a 10000 user, you still have to wait 2 days. Regarding it still being listed to a 10000 user, please [consider supporting this feature request to amend that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78977/dont-show-10k-users-posts-they-cant-delete-in-the-delete-tools).

Comment: Hmmm, wonder when they changed it.  I'll revise the question. Thanks.

Comment: @Lance They didn't, actually, protection has always been at 15000. See under February on the [Recent Feature Changes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange).

Comment: Then how did the delete votes showing (2) get on it?

Comment: @Lance Because 20000 users *can* vote to delete, like I've just done so?

Comment: OK, I've edited in a link to let everyone know about the recent change.  I've also put a bounty on the feature request.  Thanks.

Comment: @Lance You're welcome, any time. It's easy to lose track of new feature changes and privilege levels that get rolled in.