# How can I find questions that have been closed for more than 3 days?

Tags: support, 10k-tools

I wish to be able to see the “recent delete votes” and “most delete votes” but have it filtered by questions that have been closed for more than 3 days – e.g. I don’t wish to see questions that I can’t cast a delete vote on.

Being able to limit this to tags I have been active in would be even better.

Comment: Oh, is this because users with >10k (but <20k) can't cast delete votes on questions closed less than 3 days? In that case, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78977/dont-show-10k-users-posts-they-cant-delete-in-the-delete-tools) The ones you can't vote on should be dimmed.

Comment: @Code, thanks thats it, I did not know what "dimmed" meant.