# Let me filter just questions in the mod tools for deletion and undeletion

Tags: feature-request, 10k-tools, vote-to-delete

I've recently gotten to 10K reputation on Sci-Fi. It's pretty cool, but there's an annoying thing about the mod tools: the lists of delete and undelete votes include both questions and answers. As I don't have the 20K Trusted User privileges, I can't vote on deleting or undeleting answers (and I can't even see how many undelete votes are on them). Because of this, the listing of answers just gets in the way of finding things to consider voting to delete or undelete.

**Can we have the ability to view just delete votes for questions (and by extension just for answers) in the moderation tools?**

Comment: While this doesn't fulfill the "filter request" the way to **tell the difference** is that deleted **questions** have a **reason** in brackets while a deleted **answer** is shown titled as the question **without** a deletion reason, see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfIwW.png - That should help while you wait to see if your feature-request will be accepted.

Comment: Sadly, whatever the reason why, the list is cluttered with questions and answers that you can't vote to delete until you reach 20k. As there isn't a way to filter by tag either, these 'moderation tools' are pretty useless. I think that I have seen the request for filters made many times without success. That would have been a very welcome change though.

Comment: related: [Don't show 10k users posts they can't delete in the delete tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/88360/165773) -- "dimming the ones that the current user can't vote on, but displaying them so there is a consistent view"

Answer (score 6):

You can differentiate questions from answers in that list. Answer hyperlinks are body-text sized, while question hyperlinks are larger.

[image]

---

I also have a userscript to toggle display of questions and answers in the 10k tools pages:

https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/10kToolsHelper.user.js ([install](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/raw/master/10kToolsHelper.user.js))

[image]

Comment: Using Tampermonkey on Firefox, this script doesn't seem to work. What program do you recommend?

Comment: @Stormblessed seems to be working on FF70. On page load wait a few seconds for all the sections to load first, then the buttons will appear.