# More clearly differentiate links to questions and answers on 10k tools landing page

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, 10k-tools

On the [moderator tools (10k tools) landing page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tools), liked questions are displayed in a somewhat larger font size than answers. It took me ages (and a peek into the developer tools of my browser) to actually find out that the different font sizes are not just a bug. In the section where questions and answers are listed together, it currently looks like this (the different colors are due to the picture taken from another SE site and due to my browsing history):

[image: "Most commented" posts with scores in one column and question titles in another; the links to questions and answers have different font sizes]

I'd vote for an improvement of this design, because it is not clear at all that the different font sizes actually have the function to differentiate between links to questions and links to answers.

It would be much better to mark questions and answers with "Q:" or "A:" respectively. This is also the way that search results of posts are displayed on all SE sites. I think this is a much better choice to clearly differentiate between links to questions and answers and should therefore also be implemented on the moderator tools page, at least in the section with links to both questions and answers.

---

It should not be too complicated to edit the CSS. Something like this would do:

```css
/* add */
.question-hyperlink::before {
  content: 'Q: ';
}
.answer-hyperlink::before {
  content: 'A: ';
}

/* delete */
.question-hyperlink {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

Comment: [Related answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/338652/1017231)

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315806/flag-history-shows-different-formatting-for-answers-and-questions/315807#315807