# Display "out of delete votes" notification after casting Nth vote instead of the N+1th 

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-delete

Right now, there is no notification that you've run out of delete votes for the day (unlike up/downvotes) and you only get a message when you try to cast the N+1<sup>th</sup> vote (where N is the total delete votes you get as per [this recent change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79015/now-that-20k-users-can-delete-answers-should-we-increase-the-number-of-daily-del)).

Sometimes I delete several in a row from the queue and sometimes my deletes are spread over the day and I don't always keep track of how many votes I've cast.

Can it be changed such that the message is displayed immediately after the last vote is cast (and for subsequent attempts as is being done currently)?

Comment: Let me guess, you're relying on the browser showing a link as "visited" to mark whether you've looked at a question and decided on voting to delete or not? :]

Comment: no not really... sometimes the questions in the queue are entirely different from when I checked the previous time. Also, I don't have 20k rep, so some of them are automatically coloured differently to indicate that I can't delete them yet. So no, I don't rely on browser colours.

Comment: Ok. Just wondering, because I do sometimes use that as a lazy way to track what I've already looked at and was mildly annoyed once for that reason by the behavior you're complaining about, heh.

Comment: Is it a major issue? You find out you have run out when you try and cast the vote, so that's only one wasted click...

Comment: It's not a major issue.. just trying to make it more efficient. And  it probably is a trivial change too