# Allow more than 5 delete votes per day

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, privileges, vote-to-delete

When you hit 10K reputation, you're able to vote to delete questions/answer that you don't own. You're allotted 5 votes per day.

Sometimes the Moderation Tools / Delete screen has a lot of valid flags for questions to be deleted. I like to be able to cast delete votes to help [clean up the trash](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/se-podcast-03/), but quickly run out of votes for the day.

Suggestions:

- allow more than 5 delete votes based on reputation.
- perhaps allow more than 5 delete votes after receiving the Marshal badge.
- suggest 20 votes per day.

Users who like to clean up the trash should be allowed to do more work.

Comment: I agree, and I've asked a similar thing here: [Now that 20k users can delete answers, should we increase the number of daily delete votes?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79015/now-that-20k-users-can-delete-answers-should-we-increase-the-number-of-daily-del)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done; see [Now that 20k users can delete answers, should we increase the number of daily delete votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79015/now-that-20k-users-can-delete-answers-should-we-increase-the-number-of-daily-del/105876#105876)