# Do I really have 30 delete votes per day?

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-delete

I got a warning message when I hit the daily limit for delete votes.

[image]

I wasn't keeping count, but I'm just wondering: Did I really have 30 delete votes for the day?

I only have 25k reputation, so by my calculations, shouldn't I have approximately 20 delete votes (5 + 15)?

Are my calculations correct?

Comment: Hm. I wonder if the formula is accidentally, instead of `5 + (R-10000)/1000`, is just `5 + R/1000`. That would give 5 + 25 for your case, which hits the maximum 30 delete votes per day.

Comment: @Grace: I got the same message yesterday, with 18k reputation. (Didn't count the votes ... shouldn't there be some visible counter for delete, close, approve votes like for simple up- and downvotes?)

Comment: Today again ... tomorrow I'll count the delete votes.

Comment: @Grace: I'm not sure that is the case.  I was able to cast well over 20 delete votes just now using Paulo's list of questions with delete votes.  I should only have had 9 but I have exceeded 19 (22 to be exact) with my 14k rep.

Comment: @Jeff Intriguing. It seems that the case is that everyone simply has 30 votes now.

Comment: @Grace: Seems so, I had just cast 8 more delete votes to reach 30 overall.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your observation is correct; there was a bug; it has been fixed. It wasn't *quite* like any of the explanations given, but to be honest it wouldn't make an interesting retelling; simply "some code didn't work quite to plan".

Answer (score 1):

I made this experiment. Here is the list of delete votes I casted before getting the message:

Found from the Moderator-Tools:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/q/7388875/600500
2. https://stackoverflow.com/q/6114493/600500
3. https://stackoverflow.com/q/6407070/600500
4. https://stackoverflow.com/q/7383556/600500
5. https://stackoverflow.com/q/7379843/600500

From a [search of `title:problem closed:1`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=16&tab=votes&q=title:problem%20closed:1):

1. https://stackoverflow.com/q/7094197/600500
2. https://stackoverflow.com/q/7129767/600500
3. https://stackoverflow.com/q/3192037/600500
4. https://stackoverflow.com/q/6108270/600500
5. https://stackoverflow.com/q/6284883/600500
6. https://stackoverflow.com/q/4743718/600500
7. https://stackoverflow.com/q/6132723/600500
8. https://stackoverflow.com/q/6544797/600500
9. https://stackoverflow.com/q/7113476/600500
10. https://stackoverflow.com/q/7171676/600500
11. https://stackoverflow.com/q/6534411/600500
12. https://stackoverflow.com/q/7092861/600500
13. https://stackoverflow.com/q/7213337/600500
14. https://stackoverflow.com/q/7360308/600500
15. https://stackoverflow.com/q/6107147/600500
16. https://stackoverflow.com/q/6833581/600500
17. https://stackoverflow.com/q/7256183/600500
18. https://stackoverflow.com/q/3730872/600500
19. https://stackoverflow.com/q/4633630/600500
20. https://stackoverflow.com/q/5469503/600500
21. https://stackoverflow.com/q/6859422/600500
22. https://stackoverflow.com/q/6725394/600500
23. https://stackoverflow.com/q/6545469/600500
24. https://stackoverflow.com/q/7069802/600500
25. https://stackoverflow.com/q/7031098/600500

These are together 30 votes ... which shows that the popup message is not wrong.
It does not fit to [Marc's answer two days ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79015/now-that-20k-users-can-delete-answers-should-we-increase-the-number-of-daily-del/105876#105876), though, where I should have effectively only `ceil((18000 - 10000)/1000) + 5 = 13` votes.

So I'll retag this as *bug*.

(PS: I'll encourage anyone interested to vote to delete those questions, too.)

Comment: I'm getting the feeling that either the formula isn't right (and it's really just a fixed amount of 30 votes somehow) or something because I was able to cast delete votes on the first 20+ questions you listed (that wasn't already deleted) here and I only have 14k rep.