# Increase the daily number of delete votes

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-delete, rate-limiting

The daily number of delete votes seems awfully low - I can get through my 15 delete votes (as a 20k user) in a few minutes from [the delete tab on moderator tools](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete), [the 'new answers to old questions' page](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions) and/or presumably [flags](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=flags). And perhaps the more important part - I don't think 15 votes has such a big impact and I feel I could be doing more.

I propose we increase the daily number of votes.

**The way it currently is:** (based on [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79015/now-that-20k-users-can-delete-answers-should-we-increase-the-number-of-daily-de))

- 5 votes by default (starting from 10k)
- Give an extra daily vote every 1000 reputation
- Up to a maximum of 30 per day

**My proposal:**

- Below 20k - keep it as it currently is
- Upon reaching 20k, set the number of daily votes to 30 (so double it)
- From here, give an extra daily vote every 1000 (2000?) reputation
- Up to a maximum of 50 (40?) per day

**OR:**

- 5 (10?) votes by default (starting from 10k)
- Give an extra daily vote every **500** reputation
- Up to a maximum of **50** (40?) per day

**Why did I pick 20k (for the first proposal)?**

Because, as a 20k user, you get [additional privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) allowing you to vote to delete a whole lot more content: (and it would make sense to get the votes to go along with it)

- Voting to delete answers with score of -1 or lower
- Voting to delete questions with a score of -3 or lower immediately after they are closed

Comment: Why set the border to 20k? ;)

Comment: @bashophil You get more delete privileges upon reaching 20k - I added a clause to my question.

Comment: Thx although my question wasn't really meant seriously. Just had a look at your total rep.

Comment: Is there a problem with the number of votes you have? It's not that the queue is not getting emptied

Comment: @juergend I feel I could be doing more. Which queue are you talking about? There are plenty of things that needs to be deleted and plenty of ways to find them (I just listed 3 ways).

Comment: I was talking about [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete)

Comment: @Dukeling the key to supplementing one's own delete votes is to use down votes for questions that are just on the edge of getting deleted with the automated process.  A closed question with -4 score that has an answer at +1 (not accepted) only needs one down vote to get it deleted.  Down voting also can help reduce the number of delete votes needed when the automated script can't delete it and thus help reduce the overall needed delete votes for deleting specific things and allowing more cleanup to be done.

Comment: As much as I would like to see more delete votes out there for the posts that need it, I don't think giving out more votes to cast will get them deleted faster. Sure you'll be able to cast more but it doesn't help if you're the only one who voted. The problem is that we need to get more people voting to delete, not the other way around. This doesn't solve the right problem I'm afraid.

Comment: @Dukeling (for some examples, give http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/133171/cliff-questions-v2?PositiveAnswerScore=2&AnswerLen=1000&StartDate=2013.09.01&EndDate=2013.09.30&QScore=2&SumScore=2&RowsReturned=100 a run and look at the poor answers in there (though not all are bad) - single down votes will delete most of those questions and answers wholesale)

Comment: You're a 2K rep user, not a 20K. Am I missing something here? :)

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan I'm [a 20k user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1711796) on [so] (not Meta).

Comment: hehehe sorry sorry, i confused myself with your rep on meta..