# Lift or reduce the comment rate-limiting timer for moderators

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, rate-limiting

This is easily the most annoying timer on the site: post a second comment too quickly after the first, and the system kicks it back, telling you to wait 15 seconds. Count to 15 too quickly and retry, and it'll reset the timer...

Ok, I get it, we really shouldn't be posting comments that quickly. But for a moderator trying to respond to flags in a [polite but expedient manner](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/pro-forma-comments), this is an unnecessary hassle.

#### Suggestions

- Remove the comment rate-limiting entirely for moderators. If your moderator is posting trash comments, you probably have bigger problems.
- Restrict it to rate-limiting comments *on a single post*. That is, trying to rapid-fire comment on one answer fails, but posting one comment to one answer and another to another go through without a wait.
- Get rid of the infuriating timer reset. Ok, fine, gotta wait 15 seconds. It probably took me 14 seconds to get to this point anyway, so big deal. But come on, why do I have to stare at this infernal button for *another* 15 seconds?

Comment: I second all suggestions and please get rid of the timer reset for **everyone.**

Comment: I second all suggestions and please get rid of the timer reset for **10k+ users.**

Comment: Solution: Suspend everyone even looking at the car wreck and move along

Comment: Just to be clear, I hate hate *hate* the timer and always have... But I'm all about users leaving fewer comments, so, ok,  bad solution to bad problem. However, I strongly feel that *moderators* need to be as communicative as possible...

Comment: I really, really hope to see this [status-completed], at least as far as moderators go.

Comment: I suggested this as a [20k privilege](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69989/propose-a-new-20k-reputation-privilege/70007#70007) a little while back.

Comment: 26 upvotes? Stack Overflow sure loves its moderators!

Comment: @Pekka's other trolling account: lolol...

Comment: OH EFFING YES. EFFING.  YES.  This bites me every other day.  SO annoying.

Comment: While I do agree and hope this gets implemented for mods, I never felt so badly about that timer. I usually just do something else for a while longer than 15 secs and continue later on. But, again, I hardly get that timer. Just wondering, what you guys do to get it so often?

Comment: @Cawas: When we're processing flags in the moderator queue, it's common to come across several posts in a row that all need the same comment like "this should have been a new question" then deleted.  The tool @Shog9 linked to allows us to quickly add a pre-packaged comment without typing so we can go through these way faster than 15 seconds each.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the next build, moderators will have a threshold of 5 seconds rather than the default 15.

This will apply only to ♦ moderators who deal with issues very rapidly for now.

*Update:* This is now live.

*Update2:* The rate limit is now gone entirely for mods.

Comment: Happy Happy Joy Joy Happy Happy Joy Joy Happy Happy Joy Joy

Comment: @TimPost [:c](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164048/200500)