# Why rate-limit searches?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, rate-limiting

Why in the world would Stack Exchange rate limit searches?

I was just trying to do a search to find a dupe I knew was out there, and having a hard time between my typos and the arcane SE mechanism for `AND`ing search terms, got hit with this message:

> You can only perform 6 searches within
>   a 60 second window, please wait a
>   moment and try again.

**Could we please eliminate this rate-limit?**  Seems like it would simplify the code-base not to have it.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84311/please-increase-searches-per-minute/84337#84337

Comment: I have no problem with the rate limit, as long as it's *way* higher than 6 a minute

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is now no rate-limiting on searches with the new elasticsearch, as per [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange).

As per Pang's comment, looks like the limit is actually 30 searches in 60 seconds.

Comment: Actually, it seems that [the new limit is 30 searches per 60 seconds](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhbiS.png) (I tested it on SO and meta SO).

Answer (score 8):

Searches are very resource intensive; unbounded searches is a quick DDOS vector for the network.

If you can't live within the very generous 6 searches per 60 seconds allocation, I suggest using one of the many web search engines as a free, public alternative:

- Google
- Bing
- DuckDuckGo

Comment: @Jeff, just like with all the other denied search requests, the question is __why can't we do it better?__

Comment: @lance everything has to be rate limited; has nothing to do with 'better' but 'protecting the experience for everyone'. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/02/rate-limiting-and-velocity-checking.html aka *why can't 7-11 make the experience better for students in the store?* is the wrong question, my friend.

Comment: @Jeff, good article, but we could still up the limit.  DDOS will do A LOT more than 6/minute.

Comment: @Lance - 6/minute x millions of users on a botnet could potentially be an issue.  Go get a sandwich or something.

Comment: It would not be possible to launch a DDOS attack if you leave the anonymous search limit as it is and add a much higher **per-user** rate limit for users with rep above some threshold.  The attackers would need access to many hi-rep accounts to exceed what they can already do with no accounts.

Comment: @Jeff but as @Rick points out, unlike the store owner, you have the means to identify trustworthy users. Why not relax the restriction a bit for users above 500 or 1000 rep?

Comment: If you can only handle 6 searches per user per minute, switch to something that scales better, like Rails.

Comment: @Andrew It has nothing to do with hardware or software performance... If you read the comments above you will see that the limitations are there as a preventative measure.

Answer (score 5):

If all 20,000 active-ish users submitted six queries per minute or ten queries per minute, I imagine the site would be pretty well hammered with either setting.

Perhaps the scheduling algorithm could be more like an OS CPU scheduler: grant upwards of twelve to twenty queries per minute per user at idle and scale down to six per minute per user when under moderate load. (>60 searches in the last minute? >100 searches in the last minute?) You could scale even lower if you pass a boundary that suggests more than 100 accounts are involved in DDoSing via searches.