# Please reduce by half search throttling

Tags: feature-request, search, rate-limiting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why rate-limit searches?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96942/why-rate-limit-searches)

I got the following error message on Super User:

> You can only perform 6 searches within
>   a 60 second window, please wait a
>   moment and try again.

It should be fairly obvious that I'm a legitimate user (reputation 241), not a scraper or a [DDOS bot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96942/why-rate-limit-searches/96944#96944).

If you improve the search so that it's not as awful as it currently is, then maybe 6 searches in a 60 second window ought to be enough for anybody, but as it is, please at least double the permitted searches.

Comment: It doesn't take at least 10 seconds each to scan a full page of search results?  You are a bot!

Comment: @Daniel DiPaolo: Only a werewolf would say that!