# Is a feature request addressing the same problem but with a different solution an exact duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, meta

The question [Please reduce by half search throttling](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97671/please-reduce-by-half-search-throttling) was closed as an exact duplicate of [Why rate-limit searches?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96942/why-rate-limit-searches) .

Although they are discussing the same problem, I think they make different requests: one requests eliminating the throttling (rejected as not feasible), while the other requests reducing the throttling.

Are feature requests treated as exact duplicates merely because they discuss the same problem? Or were they regarded as advocating the same solution?

Comment: And it was four before: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84311/please-increase-searches-per-minute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Background:**  Please read the first answer to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54779) *if you haven't already*.  That said, there have been a fair number of proposals for improving the search functionality.  Many of them having already been implemented.  Feel free to make a feature request for one.  That said, I don't think

> If you improve the search so that it's
>   not as awful as it currently is, then
>   maybe 6 searches in a 60 second window
>   ought to be enough for anybody, but as
>   it is, please at least double the
>   permitted searches.

Could be classified as proposing a vastly different solution, especially one which hasn't already been duplicated *itself* on other questions.

**Response:** No, it's not, but it places a higher bar on the creator to demonstrate a differential utility and highlight unique contributions to the question-base.  Also, if you feel the other question, while similar, hasn't generated an answer to your taste, feel free to offer a bounty on it.