# Having a Google Instant like search on SE

Tags: feature-request, search

I have an query regarding the search structure in SE. As per the high levels set by Stack Overflow, won't it be a good idea to have a search like Google Instant, where as the user starts searching and typing the question, matching results should keep on loading?

Is there any issue related to implementing such kind of search on SO?

Comment: From what I understand about many users here, they _hate_ Google Instant.  I don't really care for it either way.

Comment: `site:stackoverflow.com/questions Your ques...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that searches are resource intensive enough that the [rate limit on searches is pretty low](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96942/why-rate-limit-searches).

Even if users preferred it (I vaguely dislike the Google instant search) it would probably represent enough extra server load that you'd blow through your entire rate limit for searches in two or three seconds.

Comment: Also, google instant is based on a document store.  Not sure if they could even get something like that from SQL Server and lucene/solr.

Answer (score 7):

Please, **don't** make search like Google instant!

Performance issues aside, it is very annoying especially when enabled by default.