# Remove answer rate limit for community moderators

Tags: feature-request, answers, moderators, rate-limiting, moderator-abilities

A few minutes ago I set up a poll on Meta.Mathematica using multiple answers as vote options.

I ran into this rate limiter:

> [image]

I do not see the point of limiting community moderators in this way given that they are trusted with far greater responsibilities, so I am requesting that the rate limit be removed or at least greatly reduced.

The only issue I can conceive is if a moderator account is compromised it could be used to spam rapidly, but if a moderator account is compromised this is surely not the biggest problem, and there could still be a higher rate limit to handle this one contingency.

A reduced moderator rate limit has already been implemented for comments; see:

[Lift or reduce the comment rate-limiting timer for moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86784/158428)

Comment: On the other hand, if this discourages Meta polls... that's a good thing, isn't it?

Comment: @Yannis What's wrong with Meta polls?  Did I miss the memo?

Comment: ShadowWizard has edited Mr.Wizard question .. Awesome ! wizard party ?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Well, personally I don't have a problem with them, but there are various little problems. Example: [The vote fraud script breaks legitimate polling questions - A serial downvoter's lament](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/150180/162704).