# Grrrrrreat answer! By nomination

Tags: discussion

The gold ["Grrrreat answer!"](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/25/great-answer) badge requires 100 upvotes.  This is a high threshold!  A low view count answer with some *excellent* information in it will probably never reach this threshold.  Still the user's knowledge should be appreciated by more than 9 upvotes, I feel.

I'd like a way to **nominate** great answers, outstanding information that not everyone will appreciate, by the very nature of the **degree of specialization** of that information.

Comment: My vaguely related [proposal for a 20k power](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69989/propose-a-new-20k-reputation-privilege/70012#70012).

Comment: Have you considered "nominating" by upvoting the answer?

Comment: Add a bounty to the question. The more people who see it the more will upvote the good answers.

Comment: @meagar __NO__.

Comment: @bobobobo Maybe you should.

Comment: @meagar __NO__.

Comment: @bobobobo I'm just saying, that's what they're for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> This is a high threshold!

That's why it's a gold badge. They're comparatively rare and hard-to-get. If you make it easier to get, more of them will get handed out.

There are other badges for folks who toil away in obscure tags. And, of course, the satisfaction and pride of a job well-done.

Comment: ...and nothing says pwnage like getting a gold badge in the [whitespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whitespace) tag or some other oddity.

Comment: It's too bad there [aren't any (gold) badges awarded for said whitespace tag](http://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags). (yet‽)

Comment: @Nightfirecat - [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/407929/how-do-i-change-eclipse-to-use-spaces-instead-of-tabs/408449#408449) is the closest by about 30 votes at a score of 86.  It's possible.

Comment: GRRRREAT ANSWER! (just kidding. This is a normal good answer.)

Comment: btw, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728649/error-lnk2005-xxx-already-defined-in-msvcrt-libmsvcr100-dllc-something-libcm/2729823#2729823) is the answer that inspired the post.  Its really good.