# How to handle vandalism in low quality queue?

Tags: discussion, flags, spam, low-quality-posts, vandalism

I've stumbled upon such an artifact in low quality queue:

[image]

It's an obvious vandalism. Unfortunately, I've got only the options on the picture. None of the options pass.

How to proceed with such posts being either vandalism or spam? From queue I haven't even an option to flag the post...

Comment: Is this about an edit or the original version of a post? The original version can't be vandalism.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's no particularly good reason to leave a comment in these cases. Select "no comment needed" and fist-bump your good buddy "Delete".

If the post is particularly egregious, opening up a link to the post directly and flagging as "offensive/abusive" isn't a bad idea either.

#### Related: [Please provide a flag option clearly designed for gibberish, contentless posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115627/please-provide-a-flag-option-clearly-designed-for-gibberish-contentless-posts)

Comment: Small note, sometimes the OP has vandalised their own post, you can tell because there's an edit but no name. In these cases it's best to go to the post and rollback the edit rather than voting to close (only happens on questions really). Though this case doesn't look like actual vandalism...