# Why can 1 rep users post so many answers so fast?

Tags: discussion, answers, new-users, spam, rate-limiting

I just came across [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/411322/ubuntu-teminal-commands-and-usage/411335#411335) (10k only) on Ask Ubuntu ([image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9QrA.png)). A new, one-rep user just posted thirteen ["abusive"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115629/138509) answers over fifteen minutes.

Another case: a user managed to post [a dozen answers suggesting to install malware](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?body=%22run+these+commands+before+running%22) and by the looks of the comments from question authors, they were successful.

Is there ever a legitimate reason for a user, especially a new one, to post so many answers like that, especially on one question? Shouldn't they be on a more restrictive rate-limit?

Comment: I don't have the rep to see those 'answers' only your screen-shot but there is a user with a similar name that has a rep of 5 now from a couple of suggested edits. I wonder if that had something to do with it?

Comment: @PeterJ: [He has no other activity.](http://askubuntu.com/users/240325/jihad-warrior?tab=activity)

Comment: And he's still going. None in the past few minutes, though.

Comment: Take into account that all those users has different ID. But I agree, some rate limit should be in place for IP.

Comment: @Braiam: ohh, didn't catch that. That still could work though, yeah.

Comment: @Braiam recently we had similar issue on Drupal Answers, and not only UIDs changed - each "answer" was [from different IP](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/a/2842/16495).

Comment: @Mołot We had _another_ one yesterday as well, would you believe. This one made a point of saying he was using the Tor network to get around restrictions. It's a difficult battle to fight

Comment: @Clive [TOR is detectable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9861102/2389310). Limiting posts per minute for TOR users would be a (partial) solution. Sorry I wasn't there to help with flagging yesterday, I spent all day grinding and sanding wood.

Comment: Way not not refuce to let anyone on the TOR network post, unles the site mods decide that there is a good reason for users of the side to hide their ID from their goverment.

Comment: This my question is - to some extent - related: [How are spammers rate limited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368580) (But the question is about posting from the *same* user account.)

Comment: **Do not do IP bans** because some users from China (like me) **need** open proxies to access SO with a decent bandwidth.

Comment: I've reported that user and their repo to GitHub.