# How are thresholds for certain rights based on rep determined?

Tags: support, privileges

Some rights that are based on reputation seem arbitrary (e.g. you need 250+ rep to vote to reopen a closed question). How are rights based on certain rep levels determined? Can they be changed once they are set, and if so how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reputation values associated with privileges are set by Stack Exchange and have remained largely unchanged since Stack Overflow was launched.

The values are configurable on a site by site basis - private and public betas have lower thresholds for most privileges (and higher for a couple) than graduated sites. For a full comparison see:

[Reputation requirements compared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared)

Values would be changed if it was felt that users were abusing the power - in which case the threshold would be raised to limit the privilege - or not using enough - in which case the threshold would be lowered.

For example the ability to create tags requires [300 reputation on Super User](https://superuser.com/privileges/create-tags), but [1,500 reputation on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/create-tags) because it was felt that too many low reputation users were creating bad tags.

Answer (score 2):

> Some rights that are based on reputation seem arbitrary (e.g. you need 250+ rep to vote to reopen a closed question).

As mentioned in [view close votes](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/view-close-votes), this threshold is only valid for your own questions. You need 3,000 rep to [cast close and reopen votes](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions).

I don't think 250 is too high. If five more experienced users (read: with 3,000 reputation or more) voted to close a question, they're normally right. IF you edited your question and it doesn't accumulate the necessary reopen votes, you can always flag for moderator attention.

> How are rights based on certain rep levels determined?

Some have been the way they are before there even was a Meta (so the sites' owners/administrator made the decision), but [some have been discussed here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69989/propose-a-new-20k-reputation-privilege).

> Can they be changed once they are set, and if so how?

If you disagree with the rep threshold for a *specific* privilege, open a [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) or [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) here on Meta.

Comment: IIRC its 250 on beta

Comment: Illinois Interactive Report Card? I didn't realize we were talking about beta sites here.

Comment: "If I recall correctly"

Comment: @PopularDemand: That makes more sense.

Comment: In beta, casting close/reopen on your own questions is 250, on all questions is 500. IIRC private beta is 100 for both, not sure.

Comment: The sentence *You may also cast a close or reopen vote on your questions.* is buried in the [View close votes](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/view-close-votes) privilege, so the `250` rep threshold seems to count for SO too.