# Report or automatically fix problematic duplicate patterns

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

There are some patterns in a duplicate question network that indicate that something is wrong and that the duplicate links should be fixed:

- a question is closed as a duplicate of a deleted question
- a question is closed as a duplicate of a question that is itself closed as a duplicate
- cyclic closing (though I don't think that is possible anymore)
- voting or answer length/amount disparity between duplicate source and target. For example, if the question closed as a duplicate has a higher voted and longer answer than the still open duplicate target, maybe the direction should be reversed.

Duplicates to deleted questions should be reviewed, as there might be a better duplicate target. If there isn't a better duplicate, the question should be reopened.

Duplicates of duplicates could be resolved automatically, and both questions should be made duplicates of the final element in the duplicate chain.

Cases of voting disparity in duplicates should also be reviewed and the best question and answer chosen as the canonical duplicate target.

Comment: Don't forget merging.

Comment: Sometimes a question  is a closer duplicate of (perhaps almost identical to) another question  that is already closed. Choosing that as a target avoids some complaints about it not being an *exact* duplicate. So it might be on purpose.

Comment: I've heard some arguments that duplicate chains are acceptable behavior. Cyclic closing isn't possible. There's definitely closures of deleted questions though. I wish I had a way to find those quickly

Answer (score 1):

One of the real issues with getting your solutions implemented (and also *merging* which wasn't mentioned) is that most of this can only be done by mods, who are mega-busy.  Us normal users can do the research, but then the only way to communicate everything is in a flag comment, and hope a mod is interested in taking the time to fix the problem.

I think some of this could be solved by giving *trusted users* (20k+) some [more privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69989/propose-a-new-20k-reputation-privilege) in this area.

For example, give trusted users the ability to change the *Close as Duplicate* link, maybe using a queue so that other 20ks would have to agree to it.  Feature Request now asked [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172513/allow-trusted-users-to-modify-closed-as-duplicate-link).

Comment: Merging is a very scary feature, it would have to be made reversible to be able to use it more freely and maybe even give access to it to more users.

Comment: Every time I read _oh mods are mega-busy_ I wonder [what's stopping SE of getting more moderators](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196585/should-moderators-who-directly-close-a-question-be-forced-to-leave-a-comment#comment621196_196585 "'As an example, at last elections I shortlisted 7-8 candidates (not counting ChrisF), everyone of them a good fit - it was only SE decision to to get only 3 of them, not 5 nor 9.'")