# Are comments like "This is the best answer" constructive?

Tags: discussion, comments, declined-flags, comment-flags

I had flagged four comments as "not constructive" today.
They were:

> Much better answer than the accepted one

> plus yours is the better answer.

> Chuck Norris can parse HTML with regex.

> You're right :)

All four got declined.
So could anyone explain to me how these comments are constructive on any topic?

Comment: **Really like to see the answer**!! (_Does it really **need** to be deleted?_ ;) )

Comment: @Mistu4u It should be, but doing so would defeat the purpose! ;)

Comment: @AndrewBarber, Exactly. As long as, the comment is really not harmful, let it stay as it is. You can't force everybody to stick to providing sack of knowledge in every comment.

Comment: +1 this is the best question

Comment: This question should be the accepted one

Comment: (As an aside: to break out of a quote or code block, one could also abuse an HTML comment, `<!-- -->` to get separated blocks. [Example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-any-markdown-to-create-tables/139013#139013) and [its source](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/2b634ce0-67a4-4eaf-80ef-0e03a4f7aa25/view-source).)

Comment: @PeeHaa's comment should be the accepted one

Comment: Slowly I feel kidded.... stop this spamming -.-

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I agree that they are not especially constructive comments.  However...

When a comment flag shows up in the moderator queue, the moderator has two choices: they can either delete the comment, or take no action by dismissing the flag.  When a comment flag is dismissed, it shows up as "declined" in the user's flagging history.  That's all.

Some moderators don't delete comments unless they are actively harmful.  It takes less time to dismiss a comment flag than it does to delete it; some comments require opening the post to see the context of the comment before deleting it (especially the Obsolete ones).

Moderators' time is limited, so some mods prefer to use their precious mod time moderating actual posts, reserving their comment moderation for the actively harmful comments.

Comment: Good points, indeed. These comments tend not to really be *harmful*, and I can certainly see and understand a moderator skipping over them, if they aren't rude or something.

Comment: And whats the poitn of "harmfull comments" then? As absolutly wrong answers are also not allowed to be flagged as not constructive. Ofcourse i can udnerstand this point of view, but at all, specially theese "+1" comments don't even change anything if they were there or they were not, no one would notice.

Comment: @Zaibis: See my edit.

Comment: Ah, the irony...

Comment: Every time I read _oh precious mod time_ I wonder [what's stopping SE of getting more moderators](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196585/should-moderators-who-directly-close-a-question-be-forced-to-leave-a-comment#comment621196_196585 "'As an example, at last elections I shortlisted 7-8 candidates (not counting ChrisF), everyone of them a good fit - it was only SE decision to to get only 3 of them, not 5 nor 9.'")

Comment: @gnat: We hold an election every year, and added four new mods in the last election.

Comment: My only problem with this mod behavior is that it encourage those unconstructive comments if they are left, as even if flagged, they are not deleted, new users will also leave those kind of comments. That will in turn make more of them flagged... and the wheel goes on and on.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I know, I participated and voted in two recent elections

Comment: @Wesley +1 best comment here

Comment: What is the purpose of having "not constructive" and "obsolete" etc options in the flagging menu if those flags are actively ignored by the mods?

Comment: I declined the comments.  Really, they add a little bit extra information that's helpful (not just from votes). If you have under 1000 reputation, you can't really tell if an answer is 'better' because it's been around longer, or because it has more net positive votes than another answer (both of which can cause an answer to have more upvotes). So for the sub-1000 or anonymous user (which is the majority) the comment shows that people really think one answer is better, not just more popular.

Comment: I don't think Robert was trying to imply that mods *actively ignore* these flags, @Juhana - rather, they're not subject to the same sort of analysis that, say, flags on answers are. Comments are deleted pretty readily, but if there's a chance a comment is useful then it'll be left.

Comment: @gnat - Elected moderators are volunteers. We try to be efficient with the tasks we need to perform, because otherwise this would be too burdensome a job to have, even if we had a bunch more people doing it. As it is, we've had several people retire because they couldn't keep up with being a moderator any more. It's also against the philosophy of this site to have just a few people making all of the important decisions. It's healthier to have the community handle as much as it can, and reduce the number of things that require moderator attention.

Comment: @BradLarson no matter how you twist the idea to _have the community handle as much as it can_, there's [no point to decline the flag on best-answer comments](http://moderator.stackexchange.com/2011/09/september-2011-newsletter/ "see: 'Flags Too Often Marked [declined]'"). If mods are too busy, they would better just skip it and let other users kill the crappy comment with more flags.

Comment: @gnat - There have been some interesting suggestions about how the community could handle comment flags, like Kate's suggestion of a review queue: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180327/135615

Comment: @gnat, our choices are 'dismiss', 'delete', and 'edit'. There is no approve or decline. It just so happens that dismissing a comment flag marks it as declined. Don't worry about comment flags, because if the comment really shouldn't be there, it'll get deleted in due course. Of course, I'd like to start wiping all comments after some length of time, but [we all know how that went over...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180082/dealing-with-the-weeds-that-are-comments-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: @GeorgeStocker well if dismissing declines the flag even against your judgement and there's even no feature to skip, this means there is a bug in feature implementation, as the intended behavior is clearly and unambigously specified in [Mod Newsletter](http://moderator.stackexchange.com/2011/09/september-2011-newsletter/): _"you don’t want to continually send the message that their help is no longer wanted. **That is not what the feature is about**"_...

Comment: ...Regarding what to do with old comments, I wouldn't mind their auto-deletion, although I'd rather [prefer auto-hide](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/182295/revisions "as indicated by two bounties here")

Comment: @gnat I think decline for flag comments should be replaced with, "[You're not wrong, Walter. You're just an a**hole.](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=uQl5aYhkF3E&desktop_uri=%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DuQl5aYhkF3E)"

Comment: @GeorgeStocker getting a clip from Lebowsky instead of decline would be nice

Comment: @gnat I couldn't agree more. Best we can hope for is a decline with an animated gif, though.

Answer (score 14):

My personal opinion is that those comments are almost always not constructive; they are what votes are for. Especially if the totality of the comments are what you've quoted here. I have declined such flags when the comments include some useful, brief information on *why* `X` post is better than `Y`, but I delete comments like the ones you quote above on sight.

That said, the moderator in question seems to disagree with me about that! See [Robert Harvey's Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/198005/152134) for an excellent reason to disagree.

Finally, as a side note; don't worry too much about declined comment flags, especially if they aren't the massive bulk of your flags.

Comment: This answer is not much better than the accepted one.

Comment: @Shog9 +1 to your comment, much better than the ones on the other answer

Comment: @Shog9 Well, I suppose that's why it's not the accepted one! (Comment flagged! ;)

Answer (score 12):

I recently left a similar comment on another SE site. I posted an answer, it was accepted, and then the next day, somebody else posted a better answer. Because I think my answer is still useful, I don't think it should be deleted. However, the OP has moved on and will probably never change the accepted answer, so I commented to that effect on the (in my opinion) better answer.

For people who are inexperienced in the field (or just new to the site), that giant green check mark is like a flag saying "This is THE canonical answer." They may not be able to compare two answers and determine which is better just by looking at them. Voting helps, but once an answer has been accepted, no matter how many upvotes the other answers get, the accepted answer will always be at the top of the list. If the author of the accepted answer concedes that another answer is better than theirs, it is a strong indication to me that I can take that big green check mark with a grain of salt.

Obviously, this is not always the situation, but I don't think blanket-flagging all "this is the best answer" comments is a good idea.

Comment: so I commented to that effect on the (in my opinion) better answer. But this would be a better place for an edit note that every one who reads the answer gets a note like "But you can also see this[...]"

Comment: @Zaibis Excellent point.

Comment: This answer is far more useful than Robert Harvey's answer, now accepted, because it actually discusses the issues _behind_ the types of comment presented by the question -- why they might be posted in the first place, and how they can be useful -- rather than the mundane, oft-repeated, and purely administrative points of flag-handling.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: This is really an argument for the community using their votes better, not for voting by proxy in comments.

Comment: The green checkmark only indicates what the OP found most useful, not which answer is *canonical*.

Comment: @RobertHarvey *You* know what the check mark means, and *I* know what the check mark means, but 99% of people landing on the page from a google search don't know. As George Stocker commented on your answer, "the comment shows that people really think one answer is better, not just more popular." Having said that, in the particular case I wrote about, it would probably be better to edit the accepted answer as Zaibis commented.

Comment: I still don't see how you can argue that posting "+1, would vote again" comments is better than actually voting.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Where did I ever say that a comment like "+1, would vote again" is better than voting?

Comment: So you assert that "This is THE canonical answer" is a materially better comment?  You're making me reconsider my position about how these comments are not particularly harmful.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Please re-read my answer. I described a very specific situation, namely, the author of the accepted answer comments that another answer is better. And yes, I do think that such a comment, preferably with a reason included, is materially better than "+1, would vote again," because it tells users that even though the accepted answer was good enough to be accepted, the very person who wrote it thinks there is a better solution out there. Once more: `Obviously, this is not always the situation, but I don't think blanket-flagging all "this is the best answer" comments is a good idea.`

Comment: I read your answer.  Comments have only two sanctioned purposes: to clarify or to ask for clarification.  That's all.  Trying to co-opt them for other purposes is pointless.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Point taken. As Zaibis commented (and as I acknowledged, twice), it would be better to edit the accepted answer to point out that another answer is better.

Comment: That still sounds like abuse.  Edits are meant to fix problems with a post, not to insert editorial comments about a post's veracity.

Comment: @RobertHarvey What would you recommend, then? I certainly did not intend to abuse anything, and didn't realize that my action could be considered harmful.

Comment: Upvote and downvote.  The voting system is not perfect, but subverting it doesn't help make it better.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I commented in addition to upvoting the other post, so I wouldn't consider it subverting the system. But I understand your point, I won't make these sorts of comments in the future. Thank you for your input.

Comment: A comment that **clarifies** the reasons that a particular answer may be preferable to another (as I've demonstrated, albeit tongue-in-cheek, here) does not constitute voting-by-proxy, @Robert; it constitutes on-topic annotation.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: I have no problem with "This is the better answer, and here's why" comments.  It's the "+1, would vote again" comments that get the BFG-3000 treatment.

Comment: "BFG-3000"? That does mean?...

Comment: @zaibis t's a DOOM reference. I'd post a link to google, but my comment would be deleted.

Comment: @ George Stocker♦ No it woulddn't, as even "@PeeHaa's comment should be the accepted one" got declined as not constructive....

Answer (score 3):

> Much better answer than the accepted one

I don't see anything not constructive there. This is what are comments for. I can consider both answers worth upvoting, but I feel I should have right to express my opinion, which is better.

> Chuck Norris can parse HTML with regex.

This is the opposite. Certainly not constructive and doesn't belong here. But the moderator could think, it's not as bad as for raising his attention - moderators are overloaded anyway.

For me the Chuck Norris comments are also a noise, but site moderators have tools to batch remove them, based on keyword, so it would be a good poing to start a meta request for this.

Comment: The point is: If you start writing a comment there is the note " Use comments to ask for clarification or add more information. Avoid comments like '+1' or 'thanks'. In my view "Much better answerthan the accpeted one", is also just a kind of "thanks" but ok thats just my opinion, but over all better and worse is just a opinion base. thats exactly what up and downvotes are made for. you can say "this is better" by upvoting or "this is worse" by downvoting. So in my view "Much better answer than the accepted one" is just "+1" in other words. And THATS explicitly not the behavior of comments.

Comment: @Zaibis no, you haven't got my point. I can upvote both answers, there's no other mechanism to show my opinion which is better.

Comment: Nah, you just didn't got my point. If both answers are well enough to get upvoted in your eyes, they both should be that good that you don't need to clarify which is the better one. Even if one is better than the other, if the content of the answers is including all aspects, thats perfect. On the one hand the reader would get the OP question answered anyway, doesn't matter of an additional refference to the "better answer". On the other Hand if an answer is missing some informations of clearly answering the question then you just shouldn't upvote it. Thats my opinion so far.