# Why don't 10k moderators have question flags appear in their moderator tools?

Tags: discussion, review, flags, moderator-tools, 10k-tools

I noticed over the past couple days of working through the flag queues that all the flags I dealt with are on answers, not questions.

This could be that there are exponentially more flags on answers than questions and that I have just not come across a question flag, though I doubt this is the case.

In the [Help Center article about Moderation tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), there is a piece about "Can I see all flags?", however it doesn't state that questions are not visible either.

> **Can I see all flags?**
>
> No. If a user picks the flag → it needs ♦ moderator attention → other
>   option, the flag will be treated with the highest confidentiality and
>   will only be visible to community moderators and Stack Exchange
>   employees.
>
> In addition, *flagged comments and spam/offensive flags are not visible
>   to you*.

I can see an argument being made that most question flags are only able to be acted on by ♦  moderators, but there are still things the community can do on these flagged questions. For example, perhaps the question is flagged low quality due to very poor formatting and a simple edit of the question could negate that flag. Or a duplicate question flag can be turned into a close vote on our part. In other words, I believe there are benefits to seeing question flags.

**Note:** I'm not talking about "**other (needs ♦ moderator attention)**" flags.

Is it by design that question flags do not make it into the 10k moderator tools? If so, why? Would it be beneficial to allow question flags into the flag queue?

If question flags are definitely not going to be added into the moderator tools, can the Help Center page be updated to also say that question flags are not visible to us?

Comment: "Other" flags are treated confidentially because you can't predict what people will write in the space provided.  If a user flags a post complaining about some other user's behavior, and you put that flag into the 10K queue, it's not confidential anymore, is it?

Comment: I understand that, but I'm not specifically talking about "Other" flags. I agree that "Other" flags are ♦ view only.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Questions do appear in 10k tools, but they are more rare than answer flags.**

The reason there are so few question flags is that most of the question flags are handled through other methods.

- Spam and offensive flags don't appear in 10k tools (both questions and answers)
- duplicate and everything under "should be closed for another reason" go to close votes review instead, and
- other (needs ♦ moderator attention) goes to ♦ moderators only.

The only flag that causes **a question** to appear in 10k tools is "**very low quality**", and those seem to be pretty rare considering most people vote to close or simply downvote the questions instead, and the automatic flag for low quality places the question in the low quality review.

Comment: On beta sites, you may also sometimes see questions [automatically flagged as "closed without comment"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196585/should-moderators-who-directly-close-a-question-be-forced-to-leave-a-comment/196611#196611) by Community ♦. Those also show up in the 10k (well, 2k, because beta) tools.