# Add Googl(e|ing) to the low quality posts filter

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, review

Several posts deal with how "Did you google it?" type answers aren't productive.

[How to deal with "Have you tried Google?" comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76195/how-to-deal-with-have-you-tried-google-comments)

I came across this post, which isn't an altogether terrible post, but suggests googling terms more than once:  [Dumbbell weight training for distance running](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/409/dumbbell-weight-training-for-distance-running/413#413) (currently closed beta) and noticed it was absent from the /review page.

Can we have google added to `/review/low-quality-posts`?

Comment: This is clearly related to the "Are there questions that are too simple?" debate. As much as Google comments are noise, sometimes it's so simple to answer that I feel reputation generated from these is worthless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We're working on a more scientific approach to low-quality auto-flagging, by looking for similarities in posts downvoted or flagged as low quality (sort of similar to the [Kaggle contest](http://www.kaggle.com/c/predict-closed-questions-on-stack-overflow) we ran for closed questions).  This will eventually replace the semi-arbitrary regexes in place right now.

In this case, the referenced post got 2 upvotes which indicates that people found it useful (and didn't bother editing), so it wouldn't even make it into the low quality queue.