# Show "Have you tried Google yet?" when question is tagged "syntax"

Tags: feature-request, question-difficulty

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to deal with Google questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-to-deal-with-google-questions)

I find that most syntax questions I see could easily be answered by a tutorial or Google.

- [Exhibit A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792491/try-else-except-syntax-error)
- [Exhibit B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748063/syntax-to-insert-one-list-into-another-list-in-python)
- [Exhibit C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817529/syntax-for-creating-a-dictionary-into-another-dictionary-in-python)
- [Exhibit D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037014/syntax-error-in-python)

IMHO, these are some pretty bad questions*.  I propose this: when someone tries to tag a question "syntax" they get a little pop-up message saying "Have you tried Google yet?"  I was thinking it would be for maybe <1000 rep users only?

**EDIT**: I'm not sure that 1K will solve it completely.  I just saw a question easily answerable by a beginner tutorial, Google, or source code, posted by a user with >3K rep.

*D is not too bad, but it's such a common problem Googling "python print sytax error" solves it(just tried it, [first hit](http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Python/comp.lang.python/2008-12/msg03368.html), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826948/python-syntax-error-on-print)).

Comment: See: [How to deal with Google questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-to-deal-with-google-questions) - the idea is, googling the question will bring up *a SO question* among the first results...

Comment: I believe the site should be **THE** ultimate reference for every syntax question in every language *EVAR!!!*  (exclamations provided for emphasis only, and do not in any way condone equivalent usage in spam advertisements)

Comment: Ah, what a day and age we live in: **Google searches bringing up SO questions telling the OP to do a fracking Google search!**