# Should we flag a question if its very commonly available on the community?

Tags: support, clean-up

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to deal with Google questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-to-deal-with-google-questions)

Sometimes new users start asking questions which are very simple and instead of using google they ask directly on stackoverflow.
Even if they google for the same title they will be getting a lot of same kind of questions in google results.

So the point is:-

1. Should we flag that question?
2. Should we down vote that question?

Or any other suggestions?

Comment: Relevant discussion here: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a comment like this on the question:

> This Google Search turned up several
>   promising results:
>   http://www.google.com/search?q=how+do+i+move+the+turtle+in+logo

and vote to close as "Not a Real Question."

Comment: Which is a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003841/how-do-i-move-the-turtle-in-logo . I rest my case ;)

Answer (score 0):

Most of those questions are usually dupes of other questions in SO anyways, so you can flag them as *not a real question* as Robert says or *exact duplicate* if it's already out there (a quick search using the title as keywords will usually show you on the first three or four hits the dupes).