# Is it ok to google and answer the question in Stackoverflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, comments, answers, google

Is it good to search and answer the questions?

Sometimes I don't know the answer, but i know how to find one (due to familarity or previous experience). When i find a solution (which is not really mine) should i post it as an answer or as a comment?

Comment: As long as you don't be a smartass and tell them "oh and I Googled this answer because apparently you couldn't do it yourself."

Comment: As long as it's not a dupe (which google can even help you find...)

Comment: Golly I hope so. Otherwise I'm going to lose a lot of reputation points. I consider it my reward for having better google-fu than others.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should we deal with Google questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-should-we-deal-with-google-questions)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: No, it isn't. There are some questions which cannot be answered by a _simple_ Google search, rather they require some digging. Like http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/442/how-are-non-carbon-stereogenic-centers-named-s-r/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do one of two things:

- Post a link as a comment
- Read the other post, understand it, write an answer in your own words. Link to the post if you wish, and sometimes quoting the awesome parts help. You can also expand on it, nothing stopping you there.

Just don't answer with just a link/copy-paste. That's a no-no.

---

Some examples of my posts where I've paraphrased, linked, and/or quoted (Feel free to add your own examples here if you have any better ones):

- [How are non-carbon stereogenic centers named (S/R)?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/442/how-are-non-carbon-stereogenic-centers-named-s-r/443#443) Perfect example of an "I Googled that for you" post, though in the OP's defense, it required a bit more digging. In this case, I knew very little of the topic, but managed to learn a lot through Googling.
- [Why is arsenous acid denoted H3AsO3?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/537/why-is-arsenous-acid-denoted-ceh3aso3/538#538) Basically a bunch of IUPAC quotes, with explanation and expansion.
- [Differences between phenols and alcohols](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/729/differences-between-phenols-and-alcohols/730#730) Here, the question is answered by the links/quotes in itself, but I managed to expand it quite a bit.
- [Origin of field deduced from potential](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/21611/origin-of-field-deduced-from-potential/21839#21839) Link with short explanation
- I've quoted myself a few times as well: [Conservation of Energy and Momentum Regarding Forces - clarification needed](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/23231/conservation-of-energy-and-momentum-regarding-forces-clarification-needed/23239#23239), [How fictitious are fictitious forces?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/24338/how-fictitious-are-fictitious-forces/24341#24341) . Note that I've put a paragraph after the quotes to tailor the answer to the specific question.

Answer (score 8):

Why not post is an answer?

If the answer is correct the answer is correct, and you have solved someone's problem! That's the goal of Stack Overflow and the other SE sites, after all. It doesn't matter how you figured out the proper answer.

Do try and word it in your own language and not copy text wholesale (which might be copyrighted and not licensed under a permissive license).

Answer (score 2):

> Sometimes I don't know the answer, but i know how to find one (due to familarity or previous experience).

I think the *"due to familarity or previous experience"* is key here, as that enables you to value the search results before posting them.

If you truly feel the search result is okay, then I'd say posting it is fine. (In the way the other answers suggest.) Great.

But if you cannot really tell what the search result means, then please don't post it. Posting things you don't really know about might still give readers the impression that the answer was posted based on your own experience. It might even get some upvotes, just because it looks okay. Also, the sole fact that some answer was posted might keep others from even reading the question.

Or, if you can only *assume* it's okay, you could of course include some disclaimer like *"It's not really my cup of tea, but Google suggests..."*.