# Why do I get: Sorry, posts can't contain that content

Tags: discussion, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Sorry, posts can't contain that content.” what content exactly (besides lmgtfy)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39163/sorry-posts-cant-contain-that-content-what-content-exactly-besides-lmgtfy)

I am trying to edit this post: [Stack Overflow questions turning up on answerspice.com?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49891/stack-overflow-questions-turning-up-on-answerspice-com)

If I just press edit, then save without adding any new content (also if I add new content) I get an error message "Sorry, posts can't contain that content".

Obviously it could contain that content last time it was edited.

Anyone know what the offending content is?

Comment: Maybe it has too many external links in it?

Comment: The URLs of the scrapers maybe?  Can you try a new post with just those URLs to see if we're blocking them?

Comment: You can post the website URL, but make sure it's in a <pre> or something so there's no actual *link*.

Comment: This feature is rather frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

They have almost certainly banned linking to content farms.  This is why you can't link to them on meta.