# Why am I getting "Sorry, posts can't contain that content."

Tags: support, hyperlinks

I was trying to add a link to a product (FastReports.NET) to this question: [Fast report error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716970/fast-report-error)

Why am I getting the error "Sorry, posts can't contain that content." in that case?

I [found](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35256/sorry-posts-cant-contain-that-content-message-is-a-guessing-game-with-no-she) that LMGTFY links are not welcome, but what about other links?

The exact link that I tried to insert was:
`http://www.fast-report.com/en/products/FastReport.Net.html`

BTW: a hint, that the link is the cause for the warning would have been really helpful.

Comment: A hint for the cause would make it easy for spammers to circumvent blacklists.

Comment: @Flexo: yes, but imagine after entering a detailed question (lots of text, code and maybe a link) you simply get the message "sorry, posts can't contain that content"? not helpful...

Comment: So the safe way to insert links is to use a URL shortener like bit.ly

Comment: No, the safe way is to not use products from people who spam or have affiliate programs which encourage spamming. URL shorteners are an abomination.

Comment: But I still think, that this blacklist-"feature" makes things difficult for normal users, while spammers will easily find ways around it.

Comment: Spammers tend to get spotted in other ways too. The blacklist is used pretty sparingly in my experience - it takes multiple days worth or large scale spamming to end on it. Personally I wish this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29518/can-and-should-stack-overflow-automatically-rewrite-bit-ly-links hadn't been declined though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that someone spammed that link on SO and it was subsequently blacklisted. The blacklist can be accessed by moderators, but there are no comments or explanations there, so it's probably difficult to find the exact reason for this specific entry.

I did a quick search on meta and in the moderator chat room, but found nothing mentioning FastReports.

Comment: I found only [one answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5228059/447356) with such a link, maybe it was flagged as spam and moderator added the site to the list back then?

Comment: Only an SO mod could tell the number of links in deleted posts, normal users can't search for that. And it has to be an SE employee that added it to the blacklist, moderators can't edit it.

Comment: Doing a quick search, I see ~130 deleted spam answers with fast-report.com in the URL, from multiple accounts, so I can see why this might have been blacklisted.

Comment: Cheers, thanks for clarifying @kiamlaluno :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd If just I didn't repeat what Mad Scientist already said, that would have been better. I am sorry.