# What's the right behavior with people who are just too lazy to google?

Tags: discussion, behavior

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to deal with Google questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-to-deal-with-google-questions)

I'm pretty new to SO. Today I noticed a question which can be simply answered by using Google. [Listing geo-places near a user location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774274/listing-geo-places-near-a-user-location/4774355#4774355) I had the feeling the person is just looking for some one who will write a script for him (and found it). I'm not sure what is the protocol on SO for handling such questions. Was my behavior, telling him just to google how to calculate the values, wrong?

Comment: (Also, I guess your answer should have been a comment, if only as it started with *I'm not really understanding your problem*.)

Comment: @Arjan The problem isn't that the user couldn't use google. I have a feeling he was just searching for some one who will do his work for him and write the needed SQL Query.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-to-deal-with-google-questions/8726#8726

Comment: Well, then: [How to answer “do my work for me” questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60342/how-to-answer-do-my-work-for-me-questions). Yes, this site has a search option too. ;-)

Comment: I searched for lazy not homework, but you are right i could come up my self with it. So the solution is just to ignore the questions? Perhaps i shouldn't care if some one does his homework

Comment: (And, referring to your title: some more background at [Ban lmgtfy (let me google that for you) links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links).)

Comment: @kalkin I can feel your pain, I felt the same way when I started  here :) But SO's liberal stance on stuff like this is a good thing in the end. Ignoring is one option; downvoting another. In really egregious cases (with people just posting the task with no explanation or literally "plz send teh codez") I tend to downvote, closevote, and comment "SO is not a code writing service" - but that wouldn't be appropriate for the question you link to, the OP is not openly asking for getting his code written. In cases like that, either provide some pointers (manual links etc.) or ignore.

Comment: Sarcasm mode on: Don't tell him to Google it. Sure, the link to the answer will be there in the search results, but it will only result in you re-directing the person to one of those SO rip-off sites, since Google's business model is to rank sites with AdSense higher than SO. It's better to just post the original SO link.