# Ban LMGTFY links across the Stack Exchange network

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, lmgtfy

Periodically, someone on Programmers.SE gets the "clever" idea to post a LMGTFY link to a question that they don't care to answer for real. It's a silly practice and terrible for all the reasons already pointed out on the Meta Stack Overflow topic, [Ban lmgtfy (let me google that for you) links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links).

A question was posted on our meta-discussion site asking [if we should ban the practice on Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/935/should-lmgtfy-be-banned) where Robert Cartaino said if we wanted to add it to the network-wide blacklist (the aforementioned question about banning them only applied to Stack Overflow, it seems), a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) should be made on Meta Stack Overflow.

So here is that [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request). Please add LMGTFY links to the blacklist across all Stack Exchange sites. There isn't a context or topic scope where it's even remotely helpful.

Comment: Or at least give moderators the ability to set the banned content for their site.

Comment: Voting to ban useless `[tag:whatever]` links as well! ;-)

Comment: @Arjan This is a `[meta-tag:whatever]`, so it's fine ;)

Comment: @Arjan `[meta-tag:whatever]` everything or death! It was referred to as [feature-request] in the linked question on Programmers.SE; I figured actually using the tag system was a better alternative to the pseudo-tag.

Comment: It would also be nice to ban "short" links to lmgtfy as well. I believe there are web services that can "unshorten" any link (so you can see whether it goes to lmgtfy or not).

Comment: Why not just a flag? Spam/offensive/LMGTFY

Comment: @jonw If there's a technical way to blacklist the URL (which there is), that's one less flag moderators have to deal with.

Comment: I think it's a terrible thing it got banned from SO in the first place. The post gives no good reason besides "it's rude." No, it's not rude to post that as a comment. What is rude is to ask a question that could be answered with 5 seconds of Googling.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionஇ_இ The issue was hashed out in great detail in [the linked question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links). This was a request to get the results of that discussion applied to sites other than Stack Overflow. Voice your complaint on that question.

Comment: @MarkTrapp I don't have to. There is a ton of comments and answers on that question that say exactly what I just said. From the upvotes in the comments and the answers it seemed like the general consensus was that the ban was a bad idea. I don't know how to explain the upvotes to the question itself.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionஇ_இ Then I'm not really sure why you think complaining here is going to be productive. This specific request was about sites *other than Stack Overflow* and it was already resolved. You complaining about the general issue on Stack Overflow in the comments here is just noise: the linked question was for the request on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I am arguing that your argument for banning LMGTFY is invalid. You are said "It's a silly practice and terrible for all the reasons already pointed out..." No it's not. The only "valid reason" pointed out there was that it was "rude." It isn't.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionஇ_இ "It's a silly practice and **terrible for all the reasons already pointed out on the Meta Stack Overflow topic, [Ban lmgtfy (let me google that for you) links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links).**" The rationale for the request is in the other discussion. If you have a problem with the rationale presented there as it applies to Stack Overflow, voice it there.

Comment: *"The rationale for the request is in the other discussion"* Which is, as I just argued, invalid. You are basing your request on an invalid rationale. Thus, this request is just as invalid as the other one. I am complaining here because I don't want a mistake to be extended to the rest of the network.

Comment: If I could, I would give this -19199194 downvotes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While I appreciate the sentiment, we have no provision (yet..) for network-wide blacklists.

Also, I would prefer to blacklist on a per-site basis since it is such a 'big stick' solution, unless there is overwhelming evidence that it is a problem on *all sites*.

That said I can certainly institute it on programmers right now.

Comment: Fair enough, banning it on Programmers.SE at least would still be great.

Answer (score 11):

If you do this, you would need to add one exception where lmgtfy is actually a [correct and accepted answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7930/automatic-search-tool-that-used-a-link-google-or-bing/7935#7935)...

Comment: Aw, I was just going to suggest that it might be a legit topic on Web Apps. Nice work!

Comment: That question is closed, however.